# What should I do to improve my question?

Tags: support, specific-question

I'd love to know what I did wrong while asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25343299/).
It got closed and downvoted. I have a feeling that I've done something really bad and I'm even considering not trying ask more questions on Stack Overflow.

I am pretty new to asking on Stack Overflow, as usually answers that already were on the site were sufficient.

The main reason I am asking this is that I want to write better questions in future.

Comment: This doesn't seem like such a bad question to me, although I don't have any expertise in that area. I think you messed up by using words like "best" and "right choice" which makes it seem like you're asking opinions, which is frowned upon on SO. Maybe if you reworded it it would be better received. It could also use some more clarification as to what exactly you were aiming to achieve.

Comment: Trust me, nothing there qualifies as "really bad."  I've seen "really bad" here at SOI and you aren't even close.  Personally, I found the question a little confusing and had to read it three times before.  A little clarification would really help, I think.  It is a normal part of the StackOverflow process to clean up a question then ask that it be re-opened.  (And, BTW, I've gotten enough answers downvoted that its nothing to be worrysome.  So long as it doesn't happen tooo often.)

Comment: I think the reason it was closed was because you kept asking about "marking" things but never actually said what that meant. For the downvote, it was probably the same reason. You just need to be a little clearer.

Comment: One of the priblems is that I am still learning English and having hard time finding right word.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, you haven't done something really bad. There are tons of closed questions and this is nowhere near the worst.

The question was closed as *unclear what you're asking*, which was probably because you keep talking about "marking" things but never actually said what that means. You can also read one of the comments below your answer which pretty much says the same:

> You asked "Are Unicode special characters the right choice", it's difficult to highlight what you meant as "Which subset of Unicode characters should I use to mark something in text". If you can clarify that by editing the question, please do so in hopes of getting your question reopened.

---

Your new edit makes the question much more clear, but still you may want to:

- Avoid asking: Is this the right choice?
- Consider adding why you need to do this.
- Show what you have tried so far (code-wise) and why it didn't work.
- Show anything you researched and explain why it didn't help you.

Comment: I added a simple example. I can't show code-wise work as I am still working on a project for this module. I asked this question while clearing possible-problem list. I've read about Unicode but only non used characters I found were special characters but those didn't fit right as seemed reserved for Unicode own stuff.

Comment: @Kubuxu For Stack Overflow questions, it's better to try something, fail, and explain why you failed instead of asking if something *will work* or if it *would be the right choice*.

Comment: I just didn't want to commit a mistake which could slip through tests as we, as Europeans, are using extremely small set of Unicode functions.

Comment: @Kubuxu Sorry but this is just not the place to ask about what possible results of the current code are (too broad) or if an idea is as good as possible (primarily opinion based).

Comment: That's why I have asked what should I do in that situation. As you can see I got answer even before the question was put on hold. I just don't want someone to have to ask similar question and go through all of it as I am now.

Comment: @Kubuxu For that specific situation, you may want to ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com but read the [help center for that site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) *very* carefully before asking. The site you choose really depends on the question. You may also want to see some quality questions there to make sure that your question qualifies. If that site doesn't work, you can [probably find one here](http://stackexchange.com/sites)

Answer (score 1):

You cover a few things in your question, without really going into detail

"Our application sends strings which then shall be localized on client side. Sometimes those are whole strings, sometimes only substring, so we have to mark them. It would be the best if it only used Unicode as it wouldn't require any protocol changes."

This doesn't really make much sense. "Mark them"? What do you mean? "It would be best..." why exactly?

"Are Unicode special characters (0xFFF0-0xFFFF) right choice for marking such special substrings in text?"
Asking such a broad question is asking for trouble. Of course, "right choice" is opinionated, and without giving specific examples, no answers can be given

Don't worry about your English ability, as long as you are specific, grammar mistakes can be forgiven.

Comment: The OP is correct in asking *if* his current choice is sane. As Jukka's answer shows, the "right choice" is not a mere 'opinion' in this particular context. "It would be best" is explained in the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You need to avoid confusing phrases like this:

> Length: (mark)10(mark)" where 10 is length in cm but it should be processed 
>   so it is displayed as inches or mm

Because if something is 10 cm long it would be wrong to display it as 10" long or 10 mm long. Your sentence doesn't make sense, so your question could easily be marked as "Unclear what you are asking"

Perhaps you meant to say:

> Length: (mark)10(mark)" where 10 is length in cm but it should be **converted**
>   so it is displayed as inches or mm

Comment: Given the already provided context (localization) I find that example  pretty clear. Maybe not perfectly worded due to language issues, but clear enough.