# How can I improve my first ever Stack Overflow question?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

My [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334377/how-to-edit-an-array-from-another-class-in-java) on Stack Overflow was pretty damn poor, but my [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307123/how-to-reference-a-2d-array-from-static-context) (which is essentially the same question but with a bit of brain applied to asking it) was pretty good, so far as trivial questions go...

How can I improve my first post? I can't delete it, and I don't know why. Is this because it was closed then reopened?

I'd like to be seen as a helpful member of the community so please, inform me of the best manner of moving on with this specific question. Do I flag for moderator and delete it, do I try to improve it further or should I flag it as a duplicate?

Comment: You can't delete it because it has an upvoted answer...by bringing it up on meta you might attract more downvotes, be aware of that...

Comment: If it really is an duplicate you could vote to close as an duplicate.

Comment: I've seen the "meta affect" in action before.. I'd rather take a hit to my rep and come out better for it then let that question sit there in that state

Comment: You might find that the meta effect isn't all that strong at the moment, there's two featured discussions about it going on at the moment [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268779/) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/).

Comment: I think we should have a community goal to not let the meta effect kill off these questions. It seems like they're actually getting up-voted, which I can't say I mind, but let's avoid mass down-voting. It really doesn't help anyone.

Comment: As my comments to the questions JonK has linked can attest, I'm a big supporter of downvoting bad Meta questions. This is not one of those crappy questions. I happily upvoted it. Best of luck to you!

Comment: That edit is a significant improvement over the original question - it's now clear what you're doing (and where you're going wrong). Well done!

Comment: Yeah, thanks to your guys' answers I realised that when editing I was trying to keep it close to the original for god knows what reason.. I should've just rewrote it completely. However, I think I have now reached the right balance of old content and asking a proper question on SO!

Comment: +1 for actually caring about the quality of the site - you're basically in the top 0.01% of new users here on Stack Overflow. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Doorknob You guys built this thing, I'm a lowly noob attempting to better myself!

Comment: You'll notice your question is closed as a duplicate: don't think of this as a negative thing, it's just an attempt to keep the information on subjects together. I know you've been active since that first question (and most likely not making these mistakes anymore) but I just wanted to reiterate it to make sure.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It's fine, I was going to close as a dupe myself. I just wanted to make it better before doing so, I know these posts can hang around for a long while before being deleted. :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Kudos for asking on here. I'm glad to see [Can we make this meta site work for mentoring?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268779/can-we-make-this-meta-site-work-for-mentoring?cb=1) being taken to heart.

I just have a few notes of what I'm noticing when I look at your questions. First off, exactly what you said in your question here: they're pretty well the same question, just put in different ways. In the future, try to avoid that. If you come up with further information to better specify your question, edit your original post. In fact, that said, I think a hybrid of the two questions would actually make a pretty acceptable one.

When I look at a question, I generally like to see three main parts:

- The goal
- The attempt
- The problem with the attempt

Now, I say "generally" because of course those three aren't always applicable. But in your case, I'd say they are.

Stepping through, we start with the goal. This was stated in your first, although I feel like you could have been a little more concise, say, "how can I access a field in one class from another class?" Going into detail is great, but if you can come up with a solid, single-statement question that encompasses the entirety of what you're hoping to accomplish, you'll be much more likely to get a fast, spot-on answer. Generally I like to either have that question as the title, or at least bolded in your question. If you want to be really good about it, I also try to state my question at the beginning *and* rephrased at the end. Then the potential answerer gets to think about your question as they read the details, but then also isn't forced to go up and re-read it again. That sometimes is way too verbose and definitely not necessary, especially if you have a very short question. But it's something to keep in mind if you ever ask a longer one with more attempts.

Speaking of attempts, the last two kind of go together. We have an awesome statement of what you want to accomplish, but now we want to see an attempt. This is something your second one gets right, although I'd still love to see it shortened a bit. It suffers from being more or less a block of code and an error. And that's alright, sometimes, but in your case your code could be whittled down a little bit to fit more of a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your attempt doesn't always have to even compile; use it as an aid to show us that yes, you tried some things before you came to us, then give exactly what was wrong.

And an important note on attempts: remember that listing what you've tried serves two purposes. First off, it appeases those of us who'd like to see evidence that you aren't using us strictly as a code-writing service. But in many ways more importantly, it can help clarify your question. There's a reason we don't write code in full sentences, and if you can utilize that conciseness and what we all know from other aspects of coding to transfer that much more information about what you'd like to see work, we'll be that much better able to help you.

You mention wanting to help people in the future and be a helpful member of the community, which is super respectable, so including an error statement as specific as "non-static variable myGrid cannot be referenced from static context" is going to be very likely to get you showing up in search results for people wanting to do exactly what you want to do. Now, of course, the purpose of a question isn't just to put in awesome SEO. But I think that's just a side-effect of yet another detail that could have sped up a response to you.

As for why you can't delete your questions, that's just because there are answers. So yes, moderator attention or marking as a duplicate is probably your best course of action. I would, however, work to make one of them an awesome question before you make any decisions like that, though.

And just a little note, we prefer not to see tags in titles, like you said "in Java" at the end. And another thing, the details about playing boards and whatnot draw from the technical aspects of your question, so I would omit those. It's certainly okay to carry details from your implementation in, especially through variable names that wouldn't benefit to be changed, but in essence you want as much focus on the question as you can have, so extraneous information about what the big-picture program is doesn't often help. That said, when in doubt, you should probably include it.

---

Given all that, here's the gist of what I would have said:

**How do I access a field from one class in another class?**

I have created a 2d array and in another class I want to take my array and be able to perform operations on it.

My field is defined in `TypeA`, as:

```
public char[][] vals = new char[8][8];
```

But now, I'd like to define a function in `TypeB` that somehow manipulates its value.

I have tried referencing it directly in `TypeB`:

```
TypeA.vals[0][0] = 'x';
```

But this gives me a compiler error stating:

> Non-static variable myGrid cannot be referenced from static context

How can I access `vals` from `TypeA` in `TypeB`?

Comment: "I just have a few notes" - That was very misleading.

Answer (score 4):

First up, well done for coming here to ask for help :)

From the perspective of a reader, your question doesn't quite contain enough information:

```
myGrid = new char[8][8]
```

That doesn't say enough about the array based on what you're asking. Ideally here you would show the declaration (and initialisation) of the `myGrid` array. The access modifier (`private`, `protected`, `public` and default) that you used to declare that array is relevant: it directly affects the array's visibility to other classes.

Also knowing if the array is `static` or non-static is useful - again it affects how the array should be accessed, and in what contexts it *can* be accessed.

In the case of a package-private (or default) variable, you'd also need to include the package declaration found at the top of the declaring class **and** the package declaration at the top of the class trying to access it.

On top of that, the relationship between the declaring class and the accessing class matters: if the accessing class is a subclass of the declaring class it can potentially access the array in a different way than if there wasn't a parent/child relationship in play. So it would be useful if you also included the class declarations for both of the classes.

Then we come to the next line:

> Now I want to manipulate this array from other classes in my project. I tried to call

Tried to call what? It seems like there's some important stuff missing there. You've indicated that you tried something but it seems like you forgot to actually include what it was that you tried!

You've got the shell of a reasonable question there, it just needs fleshing out a little first. You're not missing a large amount of information, but the information that you're missing is quite significant to the answer.