# When is a programming question not about programming?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

Recently it seems that every time I ask a question I get told "off topic", take that to another stack site, it's not about programming. I would really rather not have my account banned from asking question (again) so clearly I am need of some guidance.

The [most recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102663/how-do-i-use-bash-to-bulk-add-a-file-full-of-ip-blocks-to-iptables) was a question which I spent some considerable time googling, and trying to find the best home for but as it really did seem that the answer was going to be to come up with a bash script I was certain that this was a programming question. After all although what I needed to control were entries for IPTables it was going to be a script that would need to do the work. However, I was, of course, wrong. Again.

This has left me with a sense that I really am either too dumb to live or expressing myself so badly that I am as good as too dumb to live.

So while I earn my way back to being able to safely ask about iterative XML generation in PHP would someone please be so kind as to educate me because, believe it or not, I do not set out to upset people on daily basis... or ever.

Comment: Although your question is about programming, it's [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: I think the question can be broken down into two parts. First, the question of how to process the list of IPs in Bash. Second, how to invoke `iptables`. Because the question was labeled with [tag:bash], I would *not* move to close because that's essentially a scripting question. `iptbles` usage is clearly Super User. Since the primary purpose of this question scripting, I would leave it open, provide the scripting answer, and suggest you might need to ask on Super User for details on `iptables`. Essentially, you get an answer for scripting, but `iptables` becomes hit or miss.

Comment: There's another school of thought, too. Invoke the "tools used by programmers clause" in the site's policies. Nearly all packages, programs and commands are used by programmers, so its a worthless criteria. But it does allow you to ask nearly any question. I've tried to get the language cleaned up, but there's no interest: [Please add verbiage in Help Center to reflect policy on site/server configurations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102663/how-do-i-use-bash-to-bulk-add-a-file-full-of-ip-blocks-to-iptables). Until "tools used by programmers" is changed, nearly everything is on-topic.

Comment: @jww The actual text says "tool primarily used for programming" This is a *much* narrower set of tools. Most software questions belong on Super User

Comment: Read the selected answer on [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269273/how-can-i-improve-my-first-ever-so-question) post, it helped me a **lot**

Comment: While many system administration tasks will involve a modicum of scripting, **way** too many Bash questions on StackOverflow are variations on "I'm a sysadmin and I feel the urge to write a tool to automate a trivial task which already exists in plentiful abundance."

Comment: @jww No. Bradley is correct. They must be tools about *programming* (e.g. IDEs/editors, linters & checkers, compilers & interpreters, , profilers & debuggers etc. this kind of stuff, not `iptables` or other OS configuration tools) or *programming related* (e.g. version control, tools for deployment & packaging, tools to create/extract documentation) not *used by programmers*. Maybe the help center should state a list of example to clear this point...

Comment: @Bakuriu - then the site needs to change the text of its policy.

Answer (score 80):

Your [question was about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102663/how-do-i-use-bash-to-bulk-add-a-file-full-of-ip-blocks-to-iptables)...

...after four paragraphs of prose that really had nothing to do with the programming question at hand:

[image]

The issues with your questions range from rambling (above), to [posting about your NVidia GPU overheating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289884/geforce-gt-220-overheating-when-3d-acceleration-used), to [asking us to recommend libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055611/cross-platform-development-from-linux-to-mobile-console-ouya-and-pc) (explicitly off topic), to [having problems with Linux screencast software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854646/washed-out-colours-with-screencast-software-but-not-screenshot-on-ubuntu-all-ve), to [using Stack Overflow to try to test SysAdmin problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202361/running-ssl-locally-on-a-hosts-redirected-domain-name-with-ubuntu-and-apache), to [more sysadmin problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197640/trick-ubuntu-into-resolving-a-domain-name-locally), to [deleting the one problem that may have actually been a programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330717/sudden-bug-in-working-codeigniter-code-fatal-error-class-ci-db-result-not-fo).

In short, your questions indicate that you don't have a firm understanding of what Stack Overflow is about, and as such you've asked quite a few questions that weren't well received.

You deleted them, perhaps thinking that'd help you -- but it doesn't. The system post-ban algorithm takes into account deleted posts too, so deleting a post won't necessarily allow you to ask more questions.

Tips:

1. Don't ramble.
2. Make sure to [read the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pages.
3. Give us a complete problem to solve, not snippets.
4. Remember, this is the internet.

Comment: It looks like it was really satisfying to squash all that extraneous waffle.

Comment: 5. Make sure your questions are actually about programming, not how to use a program, set up or configure a server, or why your hardware is overheating. Kudos to @GeorgeStocker for finding all those questions.

Comment: To be fair, [the opposite problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/254929) can be just as frustrating for someone who wants provide a helpful answer. There's a happy medium between rambling and giving absolutely no background information.

Comment: I would add # **5** to your list. High coherence principle: each question should be about one problem only, but the problem description should be complete and concise. Yes, it's a wishful thinking on my part...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - The sites policies state otherwise. "Tools used by programmers" is clearly stated as on-topic. Its worthless criteria because nearly all packages, programs and commands are used by programmers. But until that changes, nearly everything goes. I think you are right about *"...hardware is overheating..."*. I don't think that's allowed per site policies (thank god something is filtered).

Comment: @jww The policies actually say "are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming" We use lots of programs, but few are actually *for* programming. Asking how to configure an Apache server, or run a command on Ubuntu, are not tools used primarily for programming.

Comment: @jww: No, "tools used by programmers" are not necessarily on-topic.  You cut out quite a few modifiers from the real policy.  (And the real policy isn't worded especially well either).  The real target would be "Software for which the dominant usage is software development"

Comment: Bash scripts are on topic.

Comment: @George: Yes and no.  Development of a bash script from scratch isn't on topic.  Programming questions related to bash scripts must start with "I know the commands (with options and arguments) I want to spawn"... "Help me automate this using bash" is on topic.  But if OP can't do it by hand at a bash prompt, it's not a scripting question.

Comment: My problem with the "not about programming" close reason is "too broad". The reasoning "not about programming" being used when a question is too broadly about programming is silly, I think. It makes the selected reason itself too broad.

Comment: @rar How would you close the questions we get every day similar to "How do I make a game in C#?" ? (Seriously, I've seen that exact question at least three times)

Comment: I mean we should add another option that is specifically "too broad". It seems odd to close even that absurd question with the reasoning "not about programming" because the actual reason is that it's insanely broad. Even though, yes, there's much more to the potential answer than programming topics specifically.

Comment: @rar, well you wouldn't use the "off-topic" reason for that question, you use the "too broad" reason. I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for. Perhaps you saw some questions that had been closed with a wrong (or questionable) close reason? "Too Broad" is not an "Off-Topic" close reason.

Comment: I am mistaken, then.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: let me [quote it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"tools commonly used by programmers"*. ***Primarily*** has nothing to do with it. Nearly every piece of software provided by a distribution is used by programmers. Like I said, its worthless criteria because it allows nearly everything.

Comment: @jww. Look further down (item 5 on the exceptions to this rule): 
"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." The "Super User" close reason uses this text as well.

Comment: @jww, I think a question about how to write a program so that it does not overheat a GPU is clearly on-topic, whereasr a problem with a GPU overheating because it does not dissipate heat properly clearly is not.

Comment: Your point is well made. I do have a bit of a problem with excessive verbage. I shall keep that in mind with further questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The revised question (after the change highlighted in [George Stocker's answer to this meta-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269423/388520)) *is* about programming ... but now (I would say) it is a bad question for another reason: you'll note that as I write this it has already garnered three closevotes because "too broad", which is the closest approximation we have in the current system to saying "**You're asking us to write your program for you.**"  We do not, as a general rule, want to do that.

You'd probably have better luck if your question started with something like [Joshua Terrill's answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102703/388520), and then went on to an explanation of why that is the best you've been able to come up with, but doesn't do what you want because X, Y, Z.

If you are so new to this sort of thing that you have no idea even how to come up with that simple loop, even after extensive reading of the interwebs, then what you need is not a Q&A site, but an introductory programming textbook and/or a guide to shell scripting for sysadmins.  Such books may be found at your friendly local public library. (Ask the reference librarian for recommendations! That's what they're there for!)

Comment: "Too broad" is not for "They asked us to write their program for them." It's for "This topic needs to be fleshed out a lot more before we can give you a definitive answer." The scope of the problem and the solution is key.  In this case, the solution is a two line bash script -- hardly 'too broad'.  

There are instances to close "Do this work for me" as too broad -- and those are when the scope of the solution needed is far too large to be answered definitively. "Too Broad" is not a proxy for laziness alone. Downvotes are for laziness.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - We've discussed laziness and the lack of the appropriate close reason. For example, [*What happened to the “You're Just Lazy” close vote reason?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216491/what-happened-to-the-youre-just-lazy-close-vote-reason).

Comment: @PM77-1 The reason there's no close reason is that we don't want questions closed for laziness. We want them downvoted. If they're answerable, either choose to answer them or don't (As Tim Post's answer says).  If you substitute "Too Broad" for "This user is lazy" and a moderator comes across it, there's a really good chance we'll re-open it. There are strict definitions for each close reason. It's like that *for a reason*.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker (1) we *used* to have "no effort" reason, that was created at some point presumably because enough people though it was a good idea. (2) I expressed my point of view in an answer to the `Meta SE`post I linked to, so there's no need to hijack this answer.

Comment: @PM77-1 It wasn't a 'no effort', it was a minimal understanding; that no matter how you answered, the OP didn't know enough to actually make use of the answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Regardless of whether that is what "too broad" officially means, I do think that "You're asking us to write your program for you" questions -- especially when the task is trivial -- should be closed, not just downvoted.  The OP is best served in that case by an introductory programming textbook and/or course, *and so are the hypothetical future readers* to whom an answer would be useful.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: What's wrong with using "too broad" as a "proxy for laziness alone"?  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250867/close-reason-suggestion-closing-a-question-where-the-asker-wants-others-to-do-h makes it seem like "too broad" is to be used whenever a problem is either nontrivial or can be decomposed into multiple parts.  (Which, honestly, just about every question is and can be if you feel like squinting a little bit.)  Is this incorrect?

Comment: @PM77-1: People like you misinterpreting what "lacks minimal understanding" are the reason we no longer have a close reason for [questions that defy reality](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258731/103167)

Comment: That would be ideal. I would love to take the time to get really good with bash. Asking what smells like a newbie question is very hard on my ego.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to really say too much either way about this. Being a community site, different people will have differing views on what really constitutes a 'programming' question.

If we take your question about IP tables for example. IP tables themselves are not a 'programming' topic, so initially I'd say it is for something like ServerFault; but if, as you say, you wanted to manipulate them through a bash script (aka programming) it would belong on SO.

Of course, that is just one example. In general, you need to try to use your best judgment... though that seems to not work to well for you.

If your question is about a programming language, about it's syntax, how to write an algorithm etc. then it probably should be on SO. The grey area comes when your question starts to become about a specific 'tool' or program. If you could substitute the tool you are 'programming' with/for with something else, then it is probably the actual code/programming that is under question and belongs on SO, if you can't, then you might need to look for another site.

I'd try to put an example here, but I don't think I could do a worthwhile job that didn't make things clearer.