# Question should not have been closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[**This question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25362079) was recently closed for being unclear. I think the question was perfectly clear even before the edit. In fact, the question was put on hold very quickly without so much as a comment asking for clarification.

In my opinion, this behaviour is unreasonable and the question should be reopened.

Comment: *"In fact, the question was put on hold very quickly without so much as a comment asking for clarification."* Yes, this is what is supposed to happen. Unclear or inappropriate questions should be put on hold first, then a discussion can occur in the comments to improve the question. After that, the question is edited and can be re-opened.

Comment: @CodyGray: The question was not unclear. There was a comment, but nobody was around anymore. The question has been edited.

Comment: FWIW questions edited within 5 days of closure [are automatically added to the reopen queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/165773 "feature announced here"), where [3K users](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) review the changes and decide whether to reopen it or keep closed

Comment: I agree that the question is clear. I have near zero experience in php or webprogramming, but I could understand what it is asking. It was probably closed because it looks like a "do my work" type question.

Comment: @gnat: I get that, but there is nothing unclear about the question. Apparently there are some dim-witted 3K'ers out there.

Comment: some? given that there are over 20,000 3Kers at SO I would say _many_ would be a more accurate word. There is even known [Bandwagon effect in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773). One has to learn to live with that...

Comment: It really isn't all that clear. The initial phrasing is awkward, and the OP seemingly uses different terms (question/query) to mean the same thing. I gave it an edit to clarify. If there are any problems with my edit, feel free to tell me or to address them.

Comment: The original formulation was *definitely* unclear. The close reason was applied appropriately. If you'll [go back and look](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25362079/1), you'll see that the original version of the question *never asked a question*. Even in the edited version, it starts off by saying "partially solved", which doesn't make a lot of sense. *What* is partially solved? By whom? What's the solution? Wait, we don't even know what the problem is yet! Let's not be too quick to blame this on incompetent close voters, @gnat. The system is working as it should here.

Comment: @CodyGray: Yes, the original formulation was awkward. That's why I added a clear question at the end. Maybe it should've gone at the top.

Comment: @CodyGray I only wanted to point that even if the closure was unfair, there's no much sense to whine about this. Some undesirable side effects in closing system are also unavoidable - chance of occasional bandwagoning is price we pay for having 20+K users closing the questions instead of 17 (18?) moderators. And this price feels fair, particularly because there are ways to correct the errors, from [reopening edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/165773) to raising mod flags and invoking meta effect... ohh some believe the latter [is bad](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269191/839601)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The initial formulation of that question was definitely unclear. The fact that it is possible to *guess* what the OP *probably* meant is not a good reason to declare the question clear.

What often happens when a question is unclear but people answer anyway is that the awkward phrasing that *appeared* to have an obvious interpretation turns out to have a different interpretation than the one that appeared obvious to those who answered the question. This just leads to aggravation for everyone as the people who answered are told they did not understand what the OP wanted and the OP is in the unenviable position of having wasted other people's time. (I've seen it many times. Sometimes *I* was the poor schmuck who wrongly thought the interpretation was obvious. Sometimes I just happened to witness the whole thing unfold.)

It is quite proper to vote to close a question such as the one you linked to as soon as possible so that it can be *clarified* before answers are posted. And the proper thing to do for someone who thinks *they* have the obvious interpretation is to comment on the question or perform the edits necessary to make the question crystal clear.

Comment: related: [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263/839601) - "You should wait for zero seconds... If/when the question is edited to become answerable it can be reopened."