# How to check the amount of questions get reopened via the reopen queue

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

Is there a way to check the amount of questions on Stack Overflow that actually has been reopened by users' reopen votes? I didn't find the right field to query with on https://data.stackexchange.com/.

My impression is there are not many questions, once they get closed, that can be reopened successfully using the reopen queue.

Comment: Strongly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286299/closing-questions-just-makes-people-feel-really-bad-can-we-make-it-harder-in-g/286309#286309 Shog's answer contains the information you were looking for.

Comment: tl;dr: editing a question *massively* increases the chances of it being reopened. We really should display these stats somewhere...

Comment: @Shog9: Yes. More stats! MORE!