# How to handle question in the reopen queue that I voted to close?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

When working the reopen queue, I sometimes come across a question that I had originally voted to close.

1. If the question is on the reopen queue because someone else voted to reopen, I will review any additional comments and answers, but it is unlikely that I will change my mind about whether the question should be closed.
2. If it is on the reopen queue because it has been edited, it is possible that I might decide that the edit makes it acceptable, and vote to reopen.

However, in either case I may not be considered an impartial judge. Should I skip such questions, at least in case (1)? If the answer is yes, should the reopen queue avoid showing me questions that I voted to close?

Comment: You should not get it in your Reopen queue unless it was edited: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163173/168333 .

Comment: In my short experience, questions put on hold and then closed are never re-opened, no matter how well they are edited. I'm talking about tech Qs, not even mention policy related Qs. Hence, if you really honest in your question, I suggest you to re-open the question you closed if it sufficiently changed, because other folks who didn't close it won't re-open it. If you object, give a verifiable example.

Comment: The system assumes you were impartial when voting to close, so why should not be impartial when voting to re-open or remain closed? Continue to vote on questions based on their merits and quality alone and you should be fine.

Comment: @sambul35: According to the **[actual data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286309/)** (and an [older but more clearly-presented set](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286309/603977)), editing dramatically improves the chance of reopening, by median 5x or so across all close reasons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A close vote on a question which results in its closure is by no means a final end-point of the question. If the close voters did their job correctly they have chosen a close reason that best fits the issue that needs to be addressed by the original poster. Most close notices come with links to relevant topics in the help center or posts on Meta.

As pointed out by S.L. Barth, [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163173/158100) from former Stack Exchange Dev Emmet:

> If you voted to close a post, and it hasn't been edited since the time it was closed, then you won't see that post in the Reopen Queue.

explains that you only get that question in the re-open queue if it has been edited. And that was the point of closing: the question can only be answered when edited. Editing has been done, re-evaluate the post on its merits.

That is similar to a feature that exists in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). The [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) requests which are successfully closed are monitored for changes. When a post is changed a [bot](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/GraveRobber) sends a message to the room and pings the members that close voted it.

Although you might be biased, you're also the one best capable of judging if the initial issues are substantively fixed to warrant a re-open vote.