# Should edits not be put on the reopen queue immediately?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-reopen, on-hold

I asked a question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872866/how-to-implement-many-to-many-relationship-editor)) that was correctly put on hold.  I edited the question, but realized it really needed more work and edited it multiple times.  I was thinking I had five days to fix it and at the end it would be reviewed again, but now I believe this is not correct after reading [Which edits push closed questions to the reopen review queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue).  My understanding now is that only the first edit puts it on the reopen queue, and in my case the first edit probably wasn't sufficient.  It's not uncommon for writers of any type to need multiple revisions to their work, and posters may not understand a fix-it-the-first-time requirement for the reopen queue.  Users making multiple edits may wonder why their edits are ignored and their questions eventually closed.

Furthermore, from [this data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286299/closing-questions-just-makes-people-feel-really-bad-can-we-make-it-harder-in-g/286309#286309), it looks like only a tiny fraction of edited on-hold questions are reopened.  This means that the edits are wasting the time of the reopen queue reviewers.  If my understanding is correct, I'm wondering if on hold questions should not be put on the reopen queue for several hours (24?) after the **last** edit to give the poster more time to think the edits over.  This may improve the reopen ratio and reduce the time wasted by reviewers.

Comment: An aside: while the edited question is no longer an external resource request, it's unlikely to be reopened as-is: "how can I build [concept with many possible implementations]?" questions are generally closed as Too Broad. A question including specific partially-working code, and asking for assistance with that, is more likely to survive.

Comment: Great info, Paul.  That clarifies the silence.  Thank you.

Comment: Good suggestion, bad example :)...

Comment: Your question is currently in the [queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/16075455) and you can see past completed reviews on the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43872866/timeline). There runs a job every 15 minutes I believe to put questions in the review queues. So 15 minutes after your first edit, your post is eligible to be shown to reviewer. Keep in mind that the re-open queue is a slow queue. It can take some time before it is completed but there is no guaranteed outcome. If your question would still not be a good fit it will stay closed, no matter how often you edited.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like my question went from the frying pan to the fire with my edits. :-)  But the process still leaves little room for a poster to correct poor edits.

Comment: Rene, the 15 minute delay is useful, though it seems it should be changed to a longer period and it should be from the _last_ edit.  Let the user thrash on it a bit.  Also, perhaps the process should be disclosed in the "on-hold" message, so the users know a little better about what will happen to their questions.