# Rephrase/relocate question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Re https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453392/from-which-font-do-the-characters-come can anyone suggest an alternate phrasing or site that might get a more useful response than just two down-votes?

Comment: It's going to be a lot more than two downvotes in a second.

Comment: We really should put up a warning about posting links to your questions... Such a dangerous trap...

Comment: @Kendra, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/impose-a-24-hour-voting-freeze-on-questions-being-discussed-on-meta

Comment: @gunr2171 That was slight sarcasm- Though that could be an idea, put a notice on asking meta questions that posting a link to your question is subject to garner votes based on the inherent quality of the linked post.

Comment: Yup, we should tell Reddit, Twitter and the others to do that too. Traffic spikes to questions do not only come from Meta :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Oh, I realize that. Difference is... We don't control those sites. (We being used very loosely here) And a lot of the ones I'm seeing anymore are people asking for help on bad questions. If we're warning them, we don't need anything fancy. But that's just my two cents on the matter.

Comment: Perhaps http://www.identifont.com/ would be useful. Or perhaps [What the Font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/). Not everything belongs on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 8):

The question itself is off-topic because it's not a programming problem. There is no alternate phrasing of the question that would change that.

Comment: It could possibly be on-topic on graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ (if improved), according to this meta question: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/147/font-identification-on-or-off-topic

Comment: "The question itself is off-topic because it's not a programming problem." You might be interested to see the "specific reason" it was closed is given as "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow". The question is none of those.

Comment: @ChrisJJ, "find this font for me" arguably qualifies as "asking us to find an off-site resource".

Comment: @ChrisJJ The post does indeed have additional problems with it beyond the fact that it's not a programming problem, but the fact that it's not a programming problem is what means that there' really no chance at all of making it appropriate for SO.

Comment: @Frédéric ""find this font for me"" I'm not asking anyone to find a font for me. I have the font - you see it in the screen shot. I'm asking what installed font the OS uses for these characters.

Comment: "Find out what this font is" then. It's still not a SO question.

Comment: @ChrisJJ And we're telling you that that question is not a programming question.

Comment: Thanks all. The original question now has a good answer, accepted.