# Why was my flag on duplicating answers declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Whenever I come across two answers that say the same with a prolonged period of time between them, I flag the old one. Until now these flags have always been deemed helpful with the newest answer being deleted.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[The oldest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7155510/1864167):

> I have had the same problem, I had to set the "Target Framework" of all the projects to be the same. Then it built fine.

[The newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10312205/1864167):

> Check to see that your target framework have the same .net versions. I had the same problem and my class .net was 3.5 and web solution had 4.5. I synced those and then it worked :)

The answer is the same, there is just some anecdote of his particular situation. 
I think my flag was warranted so this might just be a mistake. Nevertheless bringing it up here in case there is something more to it.

Comment: Ah, the bad old argument of mods not deleting historically well upvoted bad posts...

Comment: I would go and flag the newer answer. @Mods: Which would be more helpful?

Comment: I would totally be on board with deleting late duplicate answers that were posted within the current year. In this case, more time has passed since that newer answer than the newer answer followed the older answer. While I wouldn't decline your flag, I can't help but feel like the time is better spent on more current and possibly more pressing issues.

Comment: What if the newer answer was presented in a better way than the old one?

Comment: @Salman A: Then George's answer applies. Basically, it boils down to whether the newer answer adds any value to the question. If it does, great. If it doesn't, the newer answer doesn't need to exist.

Comment: question with declined flag has 135K+ views; I'd rather bring its cleanup to meta. Or, if I flagged, I'd point high views for mod attention and referred [Atwood's guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773 "How aggressively should we maintain and improve very popular questions?") on how to maintain such questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post should have been deleted.  I'm not a mod, so until a mod acts on it the best option would probably be to invoke the meta effect and go and down vote it so that 20k users can cast delete votes on it themselves.

When I say "the post should have been deleted" there are two sources I draw upon for this.  The first in the help center [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are:
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - ***exact duplicates of other answers***
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

The wording of 'exact duplicates' is looked at in the light of the close as duplicate question: [Changes to "close as duplicate" (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux)

This does not mean plagiarism or copying but rather that the exact same *message* is being conveyed with different words.

If someone was to post an answer to the question that read:

> You should set the target framework of all the projects that are being used to the same version.

This would also be an exact duplicate, even though it uses different words.

The second source for this is based on [How aggressively should we maintain and improve very popular questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103053/how-aggressively-should-we-maintain-and-improve-very-popular-questions/103069#103069) in which Jeff Atwood says:

> 4. **If answers are to be outright deleted and not combined, they should be provably bad by concrete metrics.**
>
>    We know that quality equates strongly with length (TWSS). Therefore, answers that are strong candidates for deletion:
>
>    - belong to low rep or anon users with no real commitment to the community
>    - are provably duplicate, that is, were added well after (30+ mins later) other answers that contained the same exact information
>    - are short in length
>    - do not explain much of anything

The answer meets ***all*** of these criteria:

- The poster is a low rep, unregistered user who was last seen on May 2, 2012 and has answered one, and only one question.
- They are provably duplicate - the two answers are both saying "set your target framework to the same version".  The newer answer was posted several months after the other answer (well outside of a 30+ minute window)
- The answer is short in length: 181 characters (that includes a smiley)
- It explains nothing.  I'm not going to say the *other* answer explained anything either, but this isn't about the other answer - its about this one.

Furthermore, the user fails to meet the requirements for 'deserving' the reputation:

> 2. **Stack Overflow citizens in good standing deserve credit for their contributions.**
>
>    If an answer is correct, but weak, I'd be willing to extend the benefit of the doubt and leave a comment asking for clarification if the user
>
>    - has a significant amount of reputation
>    - is still actively participating on the site
>
>    Whereas if it is a weak answer by a user with 1 rep, or a user with 50 rep who hasn't been seen in a year, I'd be much more inclined to delete it outright.

There is additional guidance to this by another Stack Exchange employee in another answer to the site: [How aggressively should we maintain and improve very popular questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103053/how-aggressively-should-we-maintain-and-improve-very-popular-questions/103059#103059)

> > - What should we do when new answers trickle in and are dupes?
>
> Down-vote them, perhaps leave a comment noting that this answer already exists and that they should try to add something new if they really must bother. Protect the question if useful. Delete once noise-level injures the ability of future readers to evaluate new and novel answers.

I would contend that a question with 19 answers (and probably a few deleted ones too) that has duplicate answers *is* at the threshold for noise-level causing injuries for the ability of future readers to evaluate new and novel answers.  And yes, it should be down voted (three so far) and no, leaving a comment for an unregistered user who hasn't been seen in over two years will not inspire them to update the answer.

Therefore, using all the guidance and criteria available it is clear that the newer answer should be deleted.  The question is who is going to do it - a mod? or finding 18 more people (at this time) to down vote the answer so that it may be deleted by the community?

---

Pruning poor and duplicate answers is a key part to the value proposition of Stack Exchange.  Stack exchange is not a forum. It is not Yahoo Answers. The fact that the answer is +20/-3 at this time is not an indication of any sort of popularity (especially when the other answer is at +274/0) on a question with 135k views.  That isn't a "popular answer that 20 people found helpful".  That is "an answer that people voted up because it said the same thing about 0.01% of the time the page was visited."

By keeping poor answers that duplicate other answers around, Stack Overflow looks more and more like a forum and it becomes harder to find the answer.  This increase in the noise that obscures the signal is *exactly* what Stack Overflow was intended to address.

By keeping these answers the example of what an acceptable answer for other people to follow.  It doesn't matter if you say the same thing as another answer in a post.  If you use different words you get to have your answer stick around.  There is a quality problem on Stack Overflow and while people may decry the "you're taking mods time with old historical things" until these posts are addressed people will see what type of quality is acceptable on the site and *continue* to post such answers.

Answer (score 11):

I declined it because it's not a case of plagiarism, and it includes extra specificity that may help new users understand where this problem could happen.

I generally don't delete answers unless there's a clear reason to do so:

- Not an answer
- Plagiarism
- Blatant self-promotion
- noise
- spam
- Contains no information at all

In the same way we keep around duplicate questions because users say the same thing many different ways, I'm OK with keeping around answers that have been found helpful (denoted through votes) even if they may say the same thing a different way, so long as they aren't a meaning-for-meaning duplicate of earlier answers -- and this includes not just viewing it from the perspective of a seasoned user, but how a new user who may not have all the information would view it as well.

If you'd like to delete these posts on your own that's up to you; but it's patently unfair to these users for a moderator to arbitrarily decide which answer should exist; especially since we have nothing in our help center that let's users know answers that cover the same ground are not welcome by the community.

If you want to solve that issue, go ahead -- but as a moderator I can't arbitrarily decide to enforce rules we don't have.

Keep in mind: Other moderators may feel differently.  We do disagree at times, and [it's a fool that looks for logic in the chambers of the human heart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQeh132J7gE).

Comment: Personally I don't see why "I had .net versions 3.5 and 4.5 in my two projects" makes it suddenly an acceptable answer but so be it.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel 20 people found it helpful. I'm not going to delete an answer that is considered that useful.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker plagiarism isn't mentioned in in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) Just as "close as duplicate" uses 'exact duplicate', the criteria mentioned in the help center is "exact duplicates of other answers".  Having multiple answers that say 'set the "Target Framework"' is an increase in the noise in the answers making it harder for people to find the distinct answers. Preserving identical material because "someone uprooted it" lowers the value proposition of Stack Overflow being a useful resource for finding *the* answer.

Comment: The alternative to flagging it for a mod to delete it is to try to invoke the meta effect and get 19 more people to down vote the question so that it may be deleted by 20k users.  However, this is pile on voting from meta or chat that some mods have decried and tried to put a stop to.

Comment: As has often been stated, upvotes are a poor indicator for technical accuracy (or even usefulness) and are often more related to popularity and age of the post. Ideally, one would hope that the answers provided are distinct.  With very short answers they can present entirely identical information using different words. A post today that said "make sure you set the target framework to the same version" should be deleted because it was a duplicate of a previous answer. This standard should be held to older posts too.

Comment: Having multiple answers that has the same material again and again makes this look like a forum. This reduces the value of Stack Overflow as the site to go to and encourages *other* people to regard Stack Overflow as a forum and behave in forum like ways. We need to encourage the behaviors that we want to see on the site - this means pruning duplicate material in questions at times. Failure to do it makes the site less valuable as a resource for people from google - you could find the same quality on YahooAnswers in this case with dozens of duplicate answers.

Comment: In dissent of the community's apparent outcry, I support this answer. Mods are right to err on the side of not deleting stuff. It's better to have some cruft lying around because the community hasn't dealt with it yet than it is for mods to go around dropping the hammer on everything. I would *much* rather have somewhat overcautious mods than overzealous mods any day.

Comment: @jpmc26 I agree with you totally, absolutely. Mods are right to close their eyes on what's going on in a question with over 100K views. Now that Atwood is not with Stack Exchange anymore, his **[guidance on how to maintain such questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773)** should be officially declared obsolete and deprecated. Tens thousands visitors of a question should clearly see that Stack Overflow welcomes any garbage posted in answers.

Comment: "especially since we have nothing in our help center that let's users know answers that cover the same ground are not welcome by the community" -- Really? You include this in your answer *well* after MichaelT has already given you the link to the help center where it says that such answers are not welcome?

Comment: @gnat Is the sarcasm really necessary? It's not very polite, and to me it seems antagonistic. It certainly doesn't encourage honest consideration or discussion of opposing viewpoints. Seems to me that a mod's job is hard enough without people jumping down their throats when the community and a mod disagree.

Comment: @jpmc26 I find nothing sarcastic in pointing to simple, well known fact that [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171172/165773)

Comment: @gnat I'm not here to have an argument or even change your mind. If you want to try to convince me of your views, that's fine, but be just as ready to listen as you are to present your side. All I did was point out that I'm glad mods err on the side of caution. An overzealous mod is a disaster for a community, and I respect a mod that shows restraint. That's what happened here. You don't have to agree that was the right action here, but appreciate that we have a mod who thinks careful about his actions and works hard to do no harm. All I ask is that you show a little more respect.

Comment: @gnat it's only 'duplicate' information if the person viewing the question already knows the answer.  For new users, this is not duplicate information (and certainly not an 'exact duplicate' as your quote states).  I submit that the people who are looking for this question are necessarily the people who would benefit from the answer.

Comment: @jpmc26 [in 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103053/165773), it was not considered overzealous for a moderator to give an extra scrutiny to answers in a very popular question. If things are different now, I would like to learn what changed and why

Comment: @gnat It's not a universal thing, there's no 'blanket' action when human discretion is involved. A mod looks, and does what they feel is the correct thing to do, _always_ erring on the side of _not_ taking action if they're even a little bit unsure. It's not "This mod isn't enforcing policy [c]", it's "This mod didn't see a clear case to enforce policy [c]" - sometimes mods just don't agree with flags, that's all it means. Folks can always flag again, or raise a discussion, as they have.

Comment: @TimPost I don't mind them keeping an answer if (_if_) reasons to keep it were evaluated carefully. I am only quite uncomfortable when answers in very popular questions are approached in the same "generic" way as in ordinary ones... few seconds of mod attention, instinctive match to standard cases and that's all - that's all? in a question having tens thousands views?

Comment: @TimPost the Then it's a question of "how many declined flags do you want to get before you are hell banned from flagging?"  However, claiming that "it has 20 up votes so it shouldn't be deleted" is in direct contradiction of the guidance given in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/ - that just because something is uprooted *doesn't* make it privileged. This also makes it hard when a [mod tries to shut down the meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269191/289086) which would be otherwise necessary to allow the community to act on it instead. ...

Comment: ... What is the proper process for getting up voted answers that *should* be deleted given the criteria in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/ and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)? Should they be called out on meta? or flagged? or some other process? Until that is clearly described, these questions on meta questioning flags will continue to be asked and tensions will continue to simmer or rise.

Comment: @MichaelT You know, if you edit the information from the answer you want deleted into the other answer; then that would make the answer you want deleted obsolete and eligible for deletion. I think Jeff mentioned that in that meta post as well.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker but I can't edit it to make the other one more complete because it says *exactly the same thing* as the #1 answer.  "You should set the target framework of all the projects that are being used to the same version."  Any variation on that answer only needs one instance of it in the answers. It doesn't need to be said multiple ways, with a short answer, that lacks explanation.  The #1 answer is completely sufficient for that purpose.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Do you have any suggestions as to the material in `Check to see that your target framework have the same .net versions. I had the same problem and my class .net was 3.5 and web solution had 4.5. I synced those and then it worked :)` that should be in the other answer?  The first sentence is the same message.  The second sentence is an example of the poster's situation (a specific case of the general mentioned in the first). The third sentence is reaffirming the second (and implying that it is an answer).  The smily is unnecessary. I can see no material that merits moving.

Comment: @MichaelT I can see a 'for instance, if your class library is targetting 3.5 and your web project is targetting .NET 4.5, you'll see this error' would be helpful. As I've mentioned many, many, many times.  If you don't see how that information makes it 'more specific', then there's nothing I can do to show you that it is.