# Why was my answer deleted instead of permitted to exist with downvotes?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I am referring to [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21419264/1195620).

[image]

I posted the answer 10 months ago, since when it received a single upvote. In the last two days, it received two downvotes, with two helpful comments that place the downvotes in clear context.

Suddenly, two hours ago, my reputation changed again, and I discovered the answer was deleted, with an option to undelete.

Who/what deleted my answer, and what differentiates it from other answers in negative vote territory permitted to survive?

Comment: You have pro-forma comments from the VLQ queue, which means you either got flagged, or the automated system thought your answer was low quality. Clearly the community agreed.

Comment: Looks like a lot of the answers to that question need to be deleted, to go with the many that already are...

Comment: The sudden activity on that question comes from here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278631/why-was-my-flag-on-duplicating-answers-declined

Comment: This is more a problem with the question than with the answers. The question just posts an error message, which is a pretty terrible question. It attracts very low quality answers, which all just repeat "well this is what caused it for me" and we end up with this long list of causes with solutions which may or may not be relevant to the original question.

Comment: I already was wondering in then [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2757366#2757366)

Comment: Ask the reviewers: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6433516 . It was flagged as "not an answer" and deleted by them in review.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question you attached that answer to is one of those "throw spaghetti against the wall" questions, where everyone solved it in a different way.  It's a forum post, in the worst possible way.

Despite all of the upvotes and the views, it's actually quite unfortunate that this question remains on the Internet, as the hapless viewer must slog through every answer to find the answer variation that solves his specific problem.   Seven answers were of such poor quality that they were deleted, and five of the remaining answers have negative votes.

It would have been better had someone written an answer that explains why this occurs (the number of actual reasons is quite small).  Instead, we get this collection-plate question, where everyone weighs in on their specific thing that appeared to solve the problem for them.  (I rebooted my machine, I painted the monitor green, I... well, you get the point).