# Does up vote of an answer necessarily entail someone found it useful?

Tags: discussion, voting, upvotes

I've often seen people proclaim "the answer had 40 upvotes, therefore 40 people found it useful".  An example of this can be seen in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278631/why-was-my-flag-on-duplicating-answers-declined/278632#comment125547_278632).

I want to contend that this isn't the case.

I personally can recall occasionally slipping into up voting posts that I didn't consider helpful to:

- Prevent them from being deleted when the user was likely to delete their account to make it non-negative
- Because I found it on the ["Hot Network Questions"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/hot-questions/info) and found it interesting (I am not going to use a squat toilet, nor will I find instructions for the use a regular of one intended for someone familiar with squat toilets useful... interesting, yes.)
- To help make a question hot
- Badge hunting the Sportsman badge (Up voted 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score) - no, I didn't find them useful, I thought my answer was better... but BADGE!
- To have an up voted answer in a question I wanted as a dup target ([related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288247/289086))
- To push someone to a [perfect reputation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQUxL.png)
- To help sort the answers in a question by the quality of the question (there are 5 answers at 0 score? This one is better than those)
- Because I hit the question via google and while one answer fixed it, the others looked good too.

<sub>Please note that above are all examples across *all* SE sites of some of my voting habits. They are in the minority of my voting habits (especially on Stack Overflow) but *rather serve as examples of how people can vote for things that are not as upvote tooltip suggests: "This answer is useful"*.</sub>

I've also seen the pseudo-default of the first post review queue be "up vote".

There are times that I wonder... just glancing around some search queries I've got... (and yes, meta effect and all -- and *no* I haven't voted on any of these answers):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377123/can-someone-help-me-understand-what-this-code-means
  Question (+0/-8):

  > The code is here
  >
  > ```
  > dat1[!is.na(dat1$jll_px),]
  > ```

  Answer (+6/-0):

  > It says "give me all rows from `dat1` where the variable `jll_px` in `dat1` is not `NA`".
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998939/jump-to-java-after-2yrs-php-experience
  Question (+2/-10):

  > I have 2yrs experience in php now I to want learn java should I go for some java(core, advanced) coaching or should I proceed further with learning joomla, cakephp, etc. Will there be any help in learning java along with php as I have done only BCA and not MCA. Also I have not even touched java before. Any suggestion would be really helpful.

  Answer (+7/-1):

  > ```
  > try {
  >     originalPoster.learnSomeJava();
  >  } catch (CantHandleLanguageException e) {
  >     originalPoster.tryAnotherLanguage();                
  >  }
  > ```
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429820/c-compile-error-c2144
  Question (+0/-7):

  > http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/443/errc.png/
  >   I don't see an error in the main function, pls help me.

  Answer (+2/0):

  > You are missing a `;` after `klog` function declaration.

Those are just from a simple search... I can get my data.se on for some other flawed gems of utility.  Other poking can find things such as:

> [image: On a question]
>   [image: On an answer]
>   [image: On another answer]

These are not "some number of people found this helpful".  The culture of voting is *not* "people found it useful" and trying to suggest policy decisions based on upvotes alone as an indication of usefulness is flawed. It may be all you have as a metric, just like your boss only has SLOC as a metric for how much work you do - but it is necessary to take into account what that metric is actually measuring, and there is an awful lot of noise mixed in with that signal.

Is an up vote an indication that something was useful?  Or should we dispense with this meme that all upvotes are because the original was helpful?

Comment: I certainly upvote answers which were not useful *for me*, because they are useful *in the context of the question*. On the other hand, visitors often have neither an account, nor the laughably little reputation required for upvoting.

Comment: I personally have never upvoted for any of the reasons you've bulleted, and if you're doing so you should stop. You've just indicated that at least a large percentage of the votes you've cast here actually are detrimental to the site, and we don't need those sorts of votes (or users) here. We should keep the meme, and start suspending or banning users who are caught (or blatantly admit) to voting for wrong reasons. Maybe you've been wasting time at this site, because you clearly don't support it's intended use.

Comment: @KenWhite you have *never* voted on an interesting answer you clicked on from the hot questions?  Actually, glancing at your network profile, that may be the case.  That said, that kind of is the *point* of hot questions as I understand it.  I would also point out that my votes are... well, you look at my vote ratio on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/289086/michaelt) and [P.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/40980/michaelt) and consider how often the "large percentage of votes" are detrimental.

Comment: I've voted on quality questions (and answers) where I find them, without regard to whether they are from hot questions, or to earn a badge, or to artificially inflate someone's reputation, or any other reason than the quality of the post I'm voting on and my assessment of it's future value here. You seem to think it's a game you play; I think of it as a place where we can collect info that helps people, and I tend to cast my votes with that in mind. Toying with your votes for whatever reason has no benefit to the overall quality or goals here. They have lots of meaningless games elsewhere.

Comment: @KenWhite once again, I'd strongly suggest that you look at my voting tendencies. I don't have the sportsman badge here. Nor have I found too many interesting SO hot questions. The voting for hot questions was on a beta site trying to get some exposure (I up voted all the answers to my question). Or that you feel that 0.003% of a person's rep is important for amusement value. Or you haven't clicked in the [hot questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220099/), or worked around the dup restrictions? or vote on the quality of answers I personally didn't use?

Comment: I am much in favour of uprooting some posts... (simple typo early on!)

Comment: You totally misinterpreted that comment.  Mods have the ability to unilaterally delete content. When content is deleted (typically) the reputation earned from it is lost. Therefore, a mod unilaterally deleting something that doesn't meet the general requirements for such (listed in the answer on which the comment is made) is, frankly, a dick move that mods shouldn't be doing. Instead, it should be left to the community to downvote and vote to delete. If there is no definitive reason why it should be deleted, and people don't want it deleted, it should therefore stay.

Comment: And I have not upvoted all questions I have found useful.( Although the ability to do so was my main reason to join SO. It all depends on the context, mainly of upvotes on the answer and other answers. I always upvote when other, imo less useful answer have more votes.)

Comment: @Will then say "we are reluctant to delete this because it will cause the loss of 400 reputation points for the OP" (which is wrong -- I will point out that posts with sufficient age and votes do not incur reputation loss - see the point beginning with "Deleting and undeleting posts may affect reputation as well" in [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/213963) - older than 60 days and +3 will *not* cause reputation loss when deleted) rather than trying to say it is *useful*.

Comment: ... There is more about the permanency of reputation on up voted posts at [Reputation and Historical Archives](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) from '12 (its been this way for 3 years): "First, if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. “Worthwhile” here is defined as,
•A score of 3 or greater
•Visible on the site for at least 60 days"

Comment: So what's the point of this question?  Yes, some people vote based on factors other than the quality of the post, so a post's score is only a rough approximation of a posts quality, and not a particularly accurate representation of it.  There are other factors that cause it to be less accurate, beyond just people voting for reasons other than post quality.  This shouldn't be news to anyone.  There are other factors that make score less accurate than this effect, such as people not understanding posts (even if they intended to vote on the quality) or the fact that score is tied to views.

Comment: I will also point out that trying to get the community to delete the material by down voting it into the negative realm and then deleting it *will* cause the loss of reputation as it will no longer be at +3. If it *should* be deleted, the dick move for a moderator is to *not* delete it when it has a positive score and instead forcing the community to remove that reputation and the post.

Comment: @Servy I'm trying to ascertain if there is rational behind saying "because this has 40 up votes 40 people found it *useful*" or if such a statement is a misrepresentation of what votes mean and the voting habits of the community at large (and even the stated intent of votes in context of hot questions). The use of the 'people found it useful' as a reason not to delete poor quality material prevents the curation of popular but useless, or duplicate material and appears to be founded on faulty premises. I really hope that people who hold this belief post an answer and point out where I am wrong.

Comment: To me you're the example of the users we dont want on this site...according to your bulleted list.  No offense...you're probably a great person, but I think your actions have negatively impacted SO...God knows how many more do the same as you.

Comment: @MichaelT To assume that exactly 40 people found it useful is of course not going to be correct.  To assume that *at least approximately* 40 people found it useful is.  Score is a *rough approximation* of the number of people that found it useful.  That doesn't mean it has no correlation with the number of people that found it useful, just that it has a (not particularly small) margin of error.

Comment: @JonH He was speaking hypothetically, saying that people give too much credence to the score of a post given the existence of people that vote using the metrics described.  He's not saying that it's good that people vote like that, rather that it's harmful to not acknowledge that some people do do it.

Comment: @JonH again, [please look at my voting history on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/289086/michaelt) and consider how often that has happened. On SO, I have *once* upvoted a post so that I could flag another post as a duplicate of it, and several times voted on other answers that are more correct and better written to help sort the quality of the answers in a post that I didn't personally find useful.

Comment: I think there is an attempt on generating information out of nothing. There is no way to generate the motivation behind upvotes and to say "they actually meant this or that by upvoting". It's about as obvious as saying "All those who did not vote actually voted party XY" in a public election. It assumes a distribution of opinions in a group not measured. If we really wanted to know why people upvote a small selection of "reasons" to choose from could clarify.

Comment: @MichaelT You phrased the question poorly.  You didn't make it sufficiently clear that you were speaking hypothetically, and gave the impression that you actually vote using the metrics you described, rather than simply saying that there exist *other* people that do.

Comment: @user2225104 Anonymous feedback from low rep users *does* provide exactly that.  Its a bit hard to get at (it used to be in the 10k tools but was too expensive on Stack Overflow with giant pivot tables).  You can still poke at it via Data.SE: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/220020/qa-anon-feedback http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209365/anon-feedback-explorer-for-user http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209364/per-post-anon-feedback

Comment: FWIW here is an [example with over 300 totally useless upvotes sprinkled over two answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269310/839601). That said, high score can make for a nice topic starter at meta discussion of the post

Answer (score 2):

An upvote doesn't mean "this personally helped me in my day", it means "this adds knowledge to the site, which we as a community deem helpful"

The fact that *you* have cast votes that don't follow that concept annoys me.

But, voting is subjective, and there's no guarantee that any individual sees voting in the same way that I do, and I absolutely support your right to vote as you see fit.  If you do so, please bear in mind that a core element of this site is measuring the quality of things, and all we've really got to go by there is the vote record, so don't be surprised when it's then *used* as a measure of quality.

If you vote for something, two things result from that: (a) the post is now harder to remove, thus you've done what you can to ensure it will remain and (b) you've raised its visibility to other users, thus you've implicitly deemed it should be put it in front of others *first*.  People generally understand this about their votes.  It's hard not to read that as an endorsement of some kind.

It doesn't *really* matter that some votes are cast against this concept.  I think it's reasonable to assume that *most* votes agree with it, and we're probably within the margin of error on that.

Comment: I'd point you to the second bulleted answer (now deleted) in the question where a joke answer was at +7/-1. There are ***many*** more of these out there when one starts digging (even the infamous html regex one - note also the scores of all the *other* answers) where vote appears to more reflect the popularity of the answer rather than its utility and thus usefulness. When digging around from a bit ago, there were a *vast* number of answers that were just links to xkcd that were highly upvoted (most of these have been cleaned up and removed).

Comment: "vast" and "many" are highly relative terms, here... are you suggesting such jokes represent a significant percentage of the overall content (pre-removal)?  Also, does it really matter?  These are legitimately times when votes don't represent true quality... but the posts are obviously jokes, and so understanding of that content is not hindered.  The fact remains that in the general case, votes are our most direct way to get at how the community judges quality.

Comment: For that matter, I'm relatively certain I've cast a few "popularity" votes myself.  It's not like I have any particular issue with that per se, but by suggesting that we *cannot* correlate votes with quality you imply that such voting makes up enough of the voting activity to make voting as a whole unreliable.  I don't believe that, but even if it's true it's still all we got.

Comment: The issue I have had is that mods have been reluctant to delete duplicate answer material (first was in '09, then there's a +20 post that is duplicate of that in '11) because the +20 represents "it was useful" even though it is completely duplicate of another answer. Then it is raised that "it is useful" represents a "I don't want delete a +20 because it will cost the person 200 rep" which is incorrect (that's not how rep works). That said, I believe that a significant portion of votes on answers on Q's posted by low rep users are from the users and not related to utility but rather courtesy.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer (in my estimation at least) is probably something proportionate to the upvotes.  This happens largely because of how many people can and do vote and how they vote.

First there are those who don't vote.  People that end up here from google, those with low rep, etc. just can not vote on the post, plain and simple.  Could they have found it useful? Sure.  Did they add a vote to affirm that to the rest of us? Nope.

This same train of thought also works for those who can vote but just don't bother to.  On top of that, maybe an answer was helpful in completing a full solution, but they never came back and voted.  Either way, we will never know how "helpful" it was.  At least it wasn't helpful enough to prompt clicking the up arrow.

Also, as has somewhat become a mantra in answering the "Why was my/this post downvoted?" questions on meta, the tooltips are guidelines that we want people to follow, but ultimately, your votes are yours to do with as you please.  Will some people upvote for some of the reasons you described? Sure.  Will some people downvote for reasons equally as "special"? Yup.

Because of all these factors, we will never be able to perfectly nail how many people an answer helped.  We just get a relative approximation.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eXT6v.png

Answer (score -4):

I've upvoted when someone has taken the time to answer my question in a method they find useful. If it works but is not exactly the answer, I'll still give them an upvote. I usually only do this for my questions though.

Comment: So you're just trying to troll any future readers of the question into thinking that this incorrect answer is in fact correct?  That's pretty cruel.  And that's not even mentioning the fact that the author now thinks that their own incorrect answer is in fact correct, they'll continue thinking that the invalid answer they gave was valid, rather than having the opportunity to learn from their mistake.

Comment: @Servy cruel or not, it is a fairly common thing done by low rep users on a site to upvote all the answers to their questions that address it. Upvotes cost nothing and when you value your *own* reputation more, one is more likely to spread the upvotes around to others who may also value the increase in reputation.

Comment: @Servy Does upvoting imply a correct answer? Hovering over the button says "This answer is useful" not "This answer is correct"

Comment: @MichaelT I didn't say nobody does it. I said it was harmful.

Comment: @Servy no matter if you like it or not (I for one don't like it), it is a simple fact of life that inexperienced askers tend to drop sympathy upvotes just for an attempt to help, no matter how poor. This is especially prominent at smaller sites where lots of such askers arrive from SO "armed" by rep bonus allowing them to upvote. Not to mention that formally, upvote tooltip can be formally interpreted as "useful" by asker because _any_ answer [meta-tag:bump]s the question and brings more eyeballs

Comment: @Shoe So whenever you find a question you hope to find incorrect answers that won't actually help you solve your problem you consider them to be useful?

Comment: @gnat I'm well aware of that.  That doesn't mean that I can't inform said user that they're being actively destructive when I notice it (or when they admit to it, as is the case here).

Comment: @Servy one can argue that from asker's perspective, _any_ answer can be considered useful, see [prior comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288245/does-up-vote-of-an-answer-necessarily-entail-someone-found-it-useful/288288#comment166780_288288)

Comment: @Servy yes it is, but its a harm that is hard to quantify when one is less familiar with the site as a whole.  Looking at the site as a whole rather than as a bunch of individuals takes some time and familiarity with it. I suspect that *everyone* when they go back to the oldest upvotes they cast they will find that they upvote nearly everything in a question. To help people move away from this mentality (and jabs, I applaud your forthcoming with this), we need to be better at showing how votes affect the site as a whole and as a resource for others.

Comment: @gnat The answerer here is saying that he's upvoting an answer that *he feels isn't useful* just because he wants to encourage the user for having posted an answer.  The fact that he is admitting to upvoting an answer that *he freely acknowledges wasn't useful to him* is the problem, and not that he found the answer useful even if other's didn't.

Comment: @Servy that's not what I read here: "when someone has taken the time to answer my question in a method they find useful. If it works but is not exactly the answer, I'll still give them an upvote"

Comment: @gnat Where in there does it say that he feels the answer he was upvoting was useful?  He's saying that he's upvoting the post purely because the person that posted it felt that it was useful, rather than because *he* felt it was useful.

Comment: @Servy "in a method they find useful" - no matter how you twist it, it won't turn into what downvote tooltip suggests, and keeps pretty close to what upvote tooltip says

Comment: @gnat Yes.  "They", not "I".  He's saying that he upvotes answers to his questions that the answerer thinks is useful, not answers that he (the question author) thinks are useful.  Seems like you just saw the word "useful" in the answer and assumed that that means that he felt the posts were useful.

Comment: ...no matter how you twist it, it won't turn into what downvote tooltip suggests, and keeps pretty close to what upvote tooltip says. Upvote tooltip says plain "useful", not "useful to me"

Comment: @gnat Again, you seem to have just seen the word "useful" in the answer and thus take it to mean that he found the answer useful.  He said no such thing.  He says he upvotes all answers to questions he's asked *regardless of how useful he thinks they are*.  That's very much contrary to the voting tooltips as it involves upvoting answers that one doesn't think are useful.

Comment: I agree with Servy on that point. The answer should be useful to the asker, not _they_ (the answerer) _find useful_. The latter is trivially detrimental because it defeats any sort of standards that are set for answers.

Comment: @Servy my point is, it's rather futile to teach one (one hundred... one thousand...) of _millions_ askers who won't follow strict rules anyway. It looks more productive to accept this as a fact of life and try to find a _systemic_ way to handle this _systemic_ deviation. For example, as it [was suggested here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601): "...dispense with the logic that preserves answers with 1 vote or an accept mark that will stay deletion at 9 days. Downvoted duplicates are also added to the mix..."

Comment: @gnat One can do both things; rather than *only* searching for technical solutions to sociological problems.  I'm certainly not opposed to the suggestions you've mentioned, but I'm not going to tell someone it's okay to take actively harmful actions at the same time.

Comment: @gnat: I most certainly did not say " He says he upvotes **all** answers to questions he's asked". I only upvote those that could be useful (they provide the right answer) but are not the way I want to implement.

Comment: @jabs: Now that's a very different statement from the one in your post: Upvoting a good answer even if in the end you decided to go a different way. And something I support.

Comment: @Servy: "If it works" != "incorrect"

Comment: @jabs You specifically said "is not exactly the answer".  So your post specifically says that it doesn't answer the question.  It "working" but not answering the question makes it an incorrect answer, by definition.