# Is it wrong to upvote an answer to a question just so you can close another question as a duplicate of it?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, upvotes

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113013/androidjava-applies-function-twice) question today, which is IMO a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325247/countdowntimer-calls-double-method) one. Same problem (`CountDownTimer.onFinish()` gets called twice), same answer (timer was being started twice).

However I couldn't mark it as a duplicate because the original didn't have an accepted or upvoted answer. The OP had actually answered their own question, they just hadn't accepted it. So, I gave it an upvote to get around the restriction and voted to close the duplicate. Is that wrong?

If so, what's the correct thing to do?

If not, why have the restriction at all if it is so easily circumvented?

Perhaps the criteria could be changed so that to close a question as a duplicate, the original question has to have either:

- An accepted answer
- An upvoted answer
- An answer by the OP

Comment: does this not pose a separate problem instead? Are these two questions really similar? Yes they both have the same answer and the same errors, but both could have been discovered from closer look at the code. The answers to these questions are only helpful in the regard of basically saying "Look closer....". I think you did right in the regard IF you find an answer that is a duplicate do what you have to to show it as long as it is actually helpful to show that it is a duplicate.

Comment: As an extension, is it wrong to immediately revert the upvote after the duplicate has been closed?

Comment: questions that are duplicates and have no answers accepted or otherwise should still be able to be closed as duplicates. This is a silly restriction to begin with. A duplicate **question** is a duplicate regardless of the quality or number of answers. This restriction leads to lots of consternation because people thing that every duplicate must have an answer that they **want** and dupes end up getting reopened just so someone can answer with a duplicate answer to get rep. But duplicate questions that have no answers are probably bad questions to begin with. Silly restriction regardless.

Comment: Dont forget that the duplicatedness of questions are not judged by the content in the questions, but their answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes (read comments)

Comment: Just a side-note on voting (both up and down): no new life is created by an upvote; nobody dies from a downvote; there is no financial impact on either the voter or the votee; there is no affect on the freedom of anyone involved (e.g. no one from (insert psycho-xenophobic-peoples-republic-under-one-family-rule-with-only-one-friend-country-and-sometimes-not-even-that here) will be allowed to leave if their question is upvoted; nobody will get tossed into a black-ops prison in Nowarezia because something is downvoted); the stock market does not rise and fall on StackExchange rep changes. Jeez...

Comment: @BobJarvis  voting allows users seeking answers to focus their research better in order to save time or avoid bad practices.

Comment: ***This question has been asked before and already has an answer.*** does not put any qualifications on the answer being duplicate only the question and that it has **an answer**, that is pretty clear. If the duplicate question poster does not understand the answer for whatever reason does **not** change the fact that the question is a duplicate. Just just want to be spoon fed the answer at this point and whine about it. If it is truly a unique question then it their responsibility to reword the question and explain why the duplicate does not solve their problem. That has been clear as well.

Comment: You can always close the earlier question as a dupe of the later one; this isn't considered bad form on StackExchange (anymore) if the later question/answer is of higher quality in some way.

Comment: This is why we need to eliminate the restriction on changing your vote.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The only way this would be *wrong* is if you were upvoting a *wrong* answer or closing a question that *wasn't* a duplicate.

So... Don't do those things.

If you've good reason to believe the answer answers the question, then up-vote it. You should probably do that anyway; that it also allows you to do something else doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: +1 for "You should probably do that anyway" - if you see a correct and useful answer to a question, just upvote it! Why not? But that's a topic for another question...

Comment: Just to add, if an answer answers two questions its bound to be relevant :).

Answer (score 30):

> Is it wrong to upvote an answer to a question ***just*** so you can close another question as a duplicate of it?

*(my emphasis)*

Yes, of course it is.

But it's never wrong to upvote a *good answer*.

So if the answer is good, upvote it. If that also lets you close a true duplicate, fine, but closing the duplicate shouldn't be the **only** reason for upvoting the answer, as the word "just" in the question suggests. If the answer didn't warrant an upvote on its own, yes, it would be wrong to upvote it purely as a means to a different end than indicating it's a good answer.

Answering [Jester's question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288247/is-it-wrong-to-upvote-an-answer-to-a-question-just-so-you-can-close-another-ques/288365#comment166776_288247):

> As an extension, is it wrong to immediately revert the upvote after the duplicate has been closed?

Yes. That's pure gaming. Either the answer was good enough to upvote, in which case leave the upvote; or it wasn't, in which case don't upvote it. If it bothers you not to be able to close-as-dupe when there's no upvoted or accepted answer, lobby for a policy change.