# I answered a question, he accepted it, and then he deleted the question!

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, unaccepted-answer

I spent a lot of time on this question:
[Open links in new tabs - greasemonkey script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701513/please-help-i-need-this-script-to-work-on-a-particular-link)

He was happy, he thanked me, wished me happy new year, and gave me the answer, and I earned 15 points.

One minute later, he removed the question. Fine by me, but I also immediately lost my points. Is there nothing to stop this happening?

Comment: This has been undeleted as a result of community votes, but if you see this happening feel free to flag and ask a mod to undelete - it bugs me when people do this too.

Comment: Just curious @Flexo, how do you flag a deleted question if you can't see the question like I assume the OP can't (based on rep)?

Comment: @Turnerj In that case, raise an "other"-flag, with link and concise description somewhere else.

Comment: It's a pretty crappy question, however, so I would hazard a guess that, unless the OP massively improves it, it will be closed for that reason.

Comment: @JörgWMittag there's a difference between closed and deleted.

Comment: Related: [Disallow deletion of questions for 24 hours after last answer was posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135538)

Comment: The user closed this due to the number of downvotes he received, most likely.  Answered or no, getting 10 downvotes means it makes more sense to delete it so they don't lose additional reputation.

Comment: The downvotes came after the deletion

Comment: Brigade downvoting a new user... is this reddit or something? I thought stackoverflow had more sense than to lash out at confused newbies.

Comment: @CBauer That's how the meta effect works. Either you get a bunch of up votes or a bunch of down-votes. The question is not a great one, but definitely does not deserved the number of down votes it has, seems people are voting based on what was said about the questioner. I've seen post with meaningless random text and spam with less down-votes.

Comment: @CBauer Well, I have to agree. I would have been happy just to get my points back, and a minor tweak of his ears. Anyway the downvoting has stopped because the question’s been put on hold.

Comment: The question now has 30 downvotes in what appears to be a perverse attempt to punish msbae for their delection, which appears to have prompted 12 pity upvotes for a total of +25 rep. Meanwhile, half of mwarren's reputation is from this answer. The system is broken.

Comment: @Saposhiente which is why we'd really need [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/impose-a-24-hour-voting-freeze-on-questions-being-discussed-on-meta) (and to be exact, [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269201/365237))

Comment: Yes, noticed that, too. I just had this question in review (Reopen Votes). While checking this page and the question to come to a decision, the previously closed question was just gone.

Comment: @GrantWinney this isn't a new precedent. [I made the same complaint with same resolution four years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74506/145673) and I'm sure there have been intervening cases. I wouldn't support "has an answer" but think there should be a delay as suggested in other comments.

Comment: i had the same problem over here exept the owner deleted it right after he realizes that it was just a simple path error pls help.. pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61846566/run-scripts-and-css-of-html-file-fetched-with-chrome-runtime-geturl?noredirect=1#comment109415460_61846566

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There is a system that avoid deletion of questions with:

- one or more upvoted answers
- multiple answers, no matter their score

I cannot see your question, but I assume it doesn't have any upvotes, and could be deleted.

Hence, I suggest to expand the above list with: <s>an accepted answer</s> as Martin Smith says, that would not have a point because people could unaccept it. A better idea (adapted from the comments) would be to disallow deletion for 8 (or another number of) hours after the latest answer has been posted. Then it has time to gain votes from the community.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. There clearly wasn't even time for somebody else to upvote my answer to his question. He was also obviously satisfied with what I had done, and I don't think he even realises that I have lost my points.

Comment: @mwarren: You didn't loose any point, since if you had upvotes it couldn't be deleted by OP.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Then what about the accepting points?

Comment: There's no point in adding "an accepted answer" to the list. If that was blocking the delete people will just unaccept then delete.

Comment: @ProgramFOX: He didn't get it before. And a lot of answers keep unaccepted....

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes I did lose my points, that's the whole point. There were no upvotes for my answer.

Comment: @mwarren: No upvotes, so no points. You got plenty now.

Comment: @PatrickHofman You're right, he has also now put it back again (or did one of you put it back??). But the question remains.

Comment: @mwarren - Three users who probably saw this question on meta voted to undelete. [You can see this in the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27701513/revisions)

Comment: A big thankyou to the people who helped put my question back. StackExchange never ceases to astonish me.

Comment: @mwarren You meant "my answer", right?

Comment: Well, yes, I suppose putting 'answer' would actually make more sense, you're right. But I was referring to the whole thing, the page - or the question - which subsequently got removed.

Comment: @mwarren The only points you lost were the points he gave you. He always has that ability, just by unaccepting, just as an upvoter can take them back by un-upvoting.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, he has the ability to unaccept, but I think mwarren's point was that unaccepting probably wasn't the intention. With it being a new (1 rep) user, he or she probably wasn't aware that deleting the question would take back the rep or that deleting an answered question once it has been answered is not the appropriate action to take on SE.

Comment: Perhaps there should be a popup asking if you really want to do that? Although I suppose just prohibiting the deletion would serve the same purpose -- if they know what they're doing, they'll unaccept and then delete.

Comment: @Barmar, they'll do it regardless. [Case in point.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305386/monty-hall-game/26305877#comment41356460_26305386) My answer was unaccepted, and then the author edited both the question and my answer to be basically a single sentence. Some people just take help for granted, after all.

Comment: @MartinSmith What about restricting deletion of a question for a certain time period after an answer is posted, to ensure it has a chance to be upvoted before getting deleted? Say, 5 minutes?

Comment: @jpmc26 - Seems sensible to me though 5 mins seems on the short side. Probably lots of decent answers don't acquire any upvotes in that time period. Especially in niche tags or off peak times. Maybe the time period should be 1 hour.

Comment: Should be much longer.  Maybe 8 hours.  This happens all the time.  Someone posts a question, often a slightly unclear one.  Lots of people contribute with comments, recommendations, requests for clarification and so on.  As soon as someone posts an answer, the OP deletes the question; thus rendering useless all the work that people put into helping them.  I have my own strategy for dealing with this.  I have a list of names of people who have done this.  They don't get any help from me on any subsequent questions that they might post.

Comment: The 8 hour delay would be good, and certainly has my vote. In my view it solves the deletion problem.

Comment: That leaves the other problem which is our inflated reputations - the OP's rep has gone up as well - which has been the side-effect of this post. Personally I believe that the meta-effect would not have happened with a 'normal' OP. Most people would have immediately left a comment saying 'Sorry guys, I didn't realise ...' or whatever and probably the reaction would have been greatly mitigated.

Comment: @DavidWallace there needs to be a shared list of such users. Everyone could benefit from it :D

Answer (score 15):

It happened to one of my answers. The following rules did not help:

> You can't delete any question that:
>
> has an upvoted answer, or
>   has multiple answers (even if there are no
>   upvotes)

The OP managed to circumvent the above conditions by un-upvoting and un-accepting my answer, then delete the question. The rules above probably need to be improved.

Answer (score 5):

I wish I could [see the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27701513/timeline) of this question, since it seems to me like it shouldn't have been deletable, but...

Per what we know about [deletable questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that):

> You can't delete any question that:
>
> - has an upvoted answer, or
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)

[The revision timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27701513/revisions) fits as well with respect to when you answered; before the second answer was added, and before anyone upvoted your answer, it was deleted *twice* by the OP, undeleted by the community, closed twice, reopened once, and during the second closure, was deleted by the community.  Somewhere in between there, a second answer was added, meaning that the OP couldn't have deleted the question themselves.

It sucks that this sort of thing does affect you, since if the question were to last 60 days, you'd keep the rep...

> Reputation changes from bounties and votes (both up and down) on deleted posts (including answers to a deleted question) are nullified. (Exception: Reputation earned for posts with a score of three or higher, and where the post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days, is retained).

...so support one of the [outstanding feature requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135538/disallow-deletion-of-questions-for-24-hours-after-last-answer-was-posted) that prevent something like this from happening.

Comment: The question was deleted because neither the question nor the answer deserves the enormous number of votes. A question with -20 net score should be deleted since it indicates that it's a bad one. Keeping bad questions/low score ones is against community rules _I assume_. A trusted user like you shouldn't have voted to undelete it. The OP (meta) came here asking for his +15, he got 10 times the rep and the OP (SO) got punished for a little mistake, rather than explaining to him/her how things go in SO.

Comment: Okay.  You're misunderstanding things.  First, the amount of votes is strictly your opinion.  Second, -20 net score could have *easily* happened due to the [Meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/1079354).  The community also seems to appreciate the answers, so I don't believe it's good to forsake the answers in spite of the question.  I felt that the answer could be useful to others in the future, so I did vote to reopen - that's my judgment call to make and you are free to disagree with it.  You'd also have to cite where it's against community rules to keep "bad" questions.

Comment: @Omar - Deleting content off the site because you don't agree with the votes it got is not the way forward. It's pretty clear the -20 was not indicative of the question quality and people were voting for other reasons. So claiming that low score = bad quality = reason to delete is plain disingenous. RE: "punishment" I didn't participate in the voting frenzy but they can't go below 1 rep. The only punishment factor would be bringing them closer to a question ban and deleting makes this worse. They should probably ask to be disassociated with the question if they care about the matter at all.

Comment: (cont'd) Just because a question is voted that heavily doesn't necessarily make it "bad".  Lastly, I did do a job of explaining what could have happened, or how it could have happened; I'm not sure what the issue is with that.  Again, I feel that the answer is still worth keeping around, even though the question does leave one wanting a bit.

Comment: @Makoto - The question was certainly nothing special, though I found the Greasemonkey bit interesting, but it wasn't delete material. Neither was my answer worthy of note. In normal circumstances we would both have been happy: he with his answer, and me with my accepted answer, and the question would have disappeared, buried with millions of others and probably hardly seen again. Before he deleted it, it had just one downvote I think.

Answer (score -2):

It happened to me right now on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813064/qopenglframebufferobject-with-multiple-texture-units). Spent a lot of time asking for details, since the OP was not even able to provide a minimum reproduceable example, and when I pointed out how to solve the problem he deleted the question...

I couldn't even read his last reply. Got the notification in my inbox and then... surprise :)

Comment: there is a system in place that prevents askers from deleting questions with answers, if however you answered in the form of a comment, there is nothing stopping the asker from doing that

Comment: Well I guess I learnt my lession :)