# Introduce no participation links for questions linked in meta

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Recently, [I answered a question, he accepted it, and then he deleted the question!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281399/3920237) has received a lot of attention, as well as [Open links in new tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27701513/3920237) the question which it discusses. While not a great question, it currently sits at a score of -20, even *after* it has been edited into shape. The current answer also sits at a score of 30,  and while I'm in no position to say whether it is a great answer, it doesn't look like it deserves that many votes.

> That script works on Greasemonkey perfectly, although there are a lot
>   of brackets that can be removed. Here is the version I used:
>
> ```
> (function(){
>         var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
>         for (i in links){
>             var href = links[i].href;
>             if(href.toLowerCase().indexOf('forum') > 0){
>                window.open(links[i].href);
>             }
>         }
>     })();
> ```
>
> Are you sure it isn't working? It may be that your browser is just
>   getting in the way and blocking popups.

The top two comments on the question, which only have to do with the meta discussion, sit at +29 and +16 score respectively. The number of views on the question also indicate high activity.

The affected [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4374299/msbae?tab=summary) has only been a member for 14 days and I was not aware this is how we treat new users. I typically see this type of mob behavior on Reddit, where its members are notorious for vote brigading and brandishing pitchforks (sic) against users they don't like.

As a result, many subreddits implement a system called "no participation" links. If you are visiting a no participation link, a large banner is displayed at the top of the page. Here is an example of a simple one (if you visit np.reddit.com/r/somesubreddit, where somesubreddit implements this):

> You have been linked to a read-only version of this subreddit. Please
>   respect the community by not voting.

Actions such as upvoting, downvoting and commenting have no effect. Users which are caught doing this typically are warned by moderators or banned (from the subreddit) if vote brigading is against the rules. Note that I am not suggesting users which circumvent this should be reprimanded, barring any other activity covered by the existing rules here. This feature-request is a simple change to *discourage* users from this kind of activity.

By anecdote, I will say these links are surprisingly effective, even if they may be easily worked around. It will not stop the meta effect, but it will certainly mitigate it. The change required would probably be minimal as well. Subreddits use CSS trickery to implement it, but obviously there is no restriction here, developers can do whatever they want. People are exceptionally lazy, and those determined can just remove "np" from the links, but that is their prerogative.

I am unsure how this should be implemented, but I would imagine the links would look something like `np.stackoverflow.com` or `stackoverflow.com/.../np`. They do not have to be real subdomains, although I imagine that a full-fledged feature would use them.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable way to mitigate the meta effect. People who feel *that* strongly about the post can always visit the real question and act.

Comment: This has been suggested before, not sure if it was on MSO or MSE...

Comment: @BoltClock: I believe it was on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269201/2074608

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy: That would be it.

Comment: @BoltClock I think that in [particular case](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27701513/revisions) referred by asker, moderators could simply apply [content dispute lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229/165773)

Comment: It is a *terrible* message to be sending to users of a website.  Because what it *really* says is "We know y'all going to go apeshit over this, as usual, you need to skip that".  We don't treat our users that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Impose a 24 hour voting freeze on questions being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/impose-a-24-hour-voting-freeze-on-questions-being-discussed-on-meta)

Comment: I was just about to suggest an NP mode, given a recent instance of a Meta Effect kicking, and now find that it's been suggested before `:-)`.