# Warning about being blocked when deleting question

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-questions, post-ban

I have a [question that I would like to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861387/iis-7-5-express-requires-vs-to-run-under-administrator-context) -- not a lot of details, no votes, under 1k of views. Unfortunately, it has an (incorrect) answer, so when I tried to delete it, I got warned of a question ban.  Should I just leave it, flag it or go ahead and risk the question ban?

Comment: The fact that there is an answer is not related here. As for should you... That's up to you.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I'm not sure what you mean by "there is an answer is not related here".

Comment: I think he meant that whether or not you get a warning when you try to delete your own question is not related to how many answers the question has.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I think you're wrong. Per my recollection, Shog mentioned somewhere at MSO/MSE that ban heuristics rather heavily penalizes removal of answered questions

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: if so, I believe he is mistaken.  I deleted a zero vote, zero answer wuestion afterwords, with no warning.

Comment: found it... sort of [cross-site duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230660/165773): "warning folks who try to delete their own *answered* questions would be a good idea even if the q-ban didn't exist - in many cases, this is just plain *rude!* So as of right now, anyone trying to delete their own question will see this"

Comment: ...and there is a bit [more detailed explanation here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168835/165773): "The folks we're concerned about are the ones who ask a question, and then delete it *as soon as they get an answer* - for whatever reasons, there are folks (and used to be more of them...) who intentionally thwart the very purpose of the site - allowing answers to go on and benefit others. It's overtly abusive behavior, and doing that repeatedly is a really good way for a new user to get blocked..."

Comment: @gnat There should be a time element in that, there's no real reason to warn people trying to delete a two year old question.

Comment: @Yannis Shog said ["It's 30 days..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168828/require-a-minimum-rep-to-delete-your-own-question/168835#comment497853_168835) but given that asker got warning on ~2 years old question, I guess something was screwed up

Comment: @gnat ahhh, hmmm... I'd missed all that!

Comment: @Yannis On the other hand, some two-year-old questions and answers are as valuable as recent ones.

Comment: @Dronz Not sure what that has to do with this discussion.

Comment: @Yannis You wrote "there's no real reason to warn people trying to delete a two year old question", but I would say there is. As the explanation in gnat's comment you were replying to said, "the very purpose of the site [is] allowing answers to go on and benefit others". Seems to me a warning would serve that, though it might be good in that case if it said, "Are you sure this question and its answers would not be of use to others?"

Comment: I think you are missing something here @Dronz. People cannot delete their own questions if they have upvoted answers. This whole discussion (and the question ban warning) only applies to questions that don't have any upvoted answers (or no answers at all). In the specific case we are discussing, the answer failed to gather a single upvote in over two years. That's a strong sign that nothing of real value would be lost if it gets deleted.

Comment: @Yannis It seems I am missing something. I agree that if there's been no answer in two years and someone is bothering to delete their own question, it probably doesn't need a warning. It sure looked like we were talking about questions with answers, and for example this question ( http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281399/i-answered-a-question-he-accepted-it-and-then-he-deleted-the-question?cb=1 ) seems to suggest it can be done. I'm sure I'm missing something though.  Not important. Just trying to help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you feel the question should be deleted, then you should just go ahead and delete it. I think the warning is a bit too eager here, I doubt anyone will miss a  question - answer pair that failed to gather a single upvote in two years.

The question ban exists to stop new users from flooding the site with low quality content. It should never kick in for someone who is following the site's rules and guidelines, and has been providing quality content for years. If it does kick in, then the problem is with the question ban algorithm.

Comment: So go ahead and press that button. Never mind us, we'll be hiding under this table...

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281464/warning-about-being-blocked-when-deleting-question#comment135706_281464

Comment: The question ban is doing a *bang up* job of keeping low quality content from flooding in.

Comment: I'm new here and still trying to figure out the "culture".  One thing is dawning on me...  Most people might think they "own" a question they post.  I know I was in shock the first time so one edited MY post; "how rude", I thought.  I know I've also deleted posts I thoght were going no where.  Maybe it needs to be clearer you don't own what you post this is one big hive.

Comment: @dan-o.  As long as it isn't doing a bang up job of keeping high quality content out as well, or more realistically, keeping out FUTURE high quality content.