# Legally republishing information from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, legal

Today, I answered a question in Stack Overflow, the OP thanks me, and just after, delete his post. I see it's not so uncommon ([I answered a question, he accepted it, and then he deleted the question!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281399/i-answered-a-question-he-accepted-it-and-then-he-deleted-the-question)).

I have a bad feeling about this.
The question is not important, delete it is not a big loss for the Stack Overflow community. But, I answered it because I see 2 upvotes on it, and no answers. I take time to answer, to explain and develop others problems on this code. 2 upvotes, it's for 3 people. Not a lot, but why not... But it's a trap (maybe some friend for upvote this?)

I suspect this is a student's question, code is very specific, and related to some exercise.
I see this deletion like a try to cheat without assume any responsibility about it.
You can make mistake, learn, use tools, like Stack Overflow, to learn more. But try to hide this, it's bad.

So, I have some history (code/question/answers). The question is:

Can I republish it, with a new formulation and with a link to Stack Overflow about source (but not a true source, because question is no more accessible for common people), on an external website, with comment (about code, only), to not lose, and my work, and the fact people search about this on Internet.?

If it's possible (legally, because, it's the point), maybe I will try to
aggregate/group all theses "deleted threads" from people who answered and don't want to lose theirs answers ( But no link to the real question, just a new formulation and no link with the OP of theses questions), and also, not lose the fact that somebody ask about this specific subject on Internet.

Comment: Do you still have a link to the post? Post it here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815058/how-to-make-a-classswitchboard-which-change-the-switches-on-and-off?noredirect=1#comment55396281_33815058 not important question, just cheat, and I fell into the trap :)

Comment: This shouldn't be the norm and there are mechanisms preventing it - as soon as there is one upvoted answer, the OP can no longer delete their question. The lesson from this specific case is that if it looks like a homework question, you should consider the possibility of not answering it.

Comment: But to answer your question, yes you can do that, as long as you respect the attribution guidelines. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Comment: Thanks. By the way, yes, no more homework answers for me :). lesson learned. I was not sure, because, "Hyperlink directly to the original question" for a deleted question, is "strange".

Comment: Am I missing something here? The question you linked was never deleted?

Comment: If it's an interesting question that may help other users, and you spent a lot of time on your answer, you could always re-post it as a self-answered question under your own name. (I know many people feel weird about posting self-answered questions, but they're perfectly within the rules and spirit of SO.)

Comment: @DavidG [Yes, it was.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33815058/revisions) But if there are no edits, if a question is just deleted and undeleted, then you don't get a link to the revision history on the question page.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Summary: it should be fine to repost deleted content**

---

I'm not a lawyer, so if you get an answer from one, ignore me.

But to my knowledge, the way it works is this: people who contribute content to SE sites do so under an irrevocable Creative Commons license. Yes, the license requires attribution, but it shouldn't be in a manner such that the original author can revoke the validity of the attribution - otherwise there would be no point in the license being irrevocable. In other words, even if the original source of the post is no longer accessible, that *shouldn't* stop you from redistributing the post (assuming you obtained it under the CC license in the first place).

Of course, SE imposes [specific requirements on attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), which would be impossible to meet if you can't even get access to the URL of the post. I don't know what should happen in this case. I think there should be some sort of provision allowing you to redistribute the post anyway, even though you can't get the original URL, but as far as I know this has never been explicitly spelled out by SE.

Here is [a related Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201609/how-does-the-creative-commons-license-affect-deleted-content) (my answer) that also addresses this issue.

Comment: What should be obvious but is worth mentioning as well: this only applies if the OP was legally able to license the content under CC rules in the first place. If content was deleted because it was plagiarised from something that came from outside of SO, for instance, then don't repost it.

Comment: Note that the linked [blog post misses an important requirement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225486/193139).

Comment: About attribution for deleted questions: if there’s no URI (or the URI no longer works, i.e., it no longer provides licensing information), you don’t have to supply it in your attribution (see my [related answer on Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256481/193139)).

Comment: @unor well, that's still not official information.

Answer (score 0):

David asked if he can legally republish his answers from a Stackexchange website elsewhere.

> Can I republish it [my answer], with a new formulation and with a link to Stack Overflow about source (but not a true source, because question is no more accessible for common people), on an external website, with comment (about code, only), to not lose my work...?

In particular, as it's your own content, yes you can. The first version was typed on your computer and then you licensed it to Stackexchange under Creative Commons Share Like v3 license with attribution.

The issue with the question is somewhat more subtle. Many questions cannot really be licensed. I.e. [no copyright is inherent to a simple question](https://www.plagiarismtoday.com/stopping-internet-plagiarism/your-copyrights-online/limitations-of-copyright/):

> There are many things which simply can not be copyrighted. Though a full list would be far too long to publish, it includes things such as titles, facts, ideas, phrases and other items which are too small or short to have any unique value. It’s important to remember that copyright does not protect an idea, just the expression of an idea.

At the most, you'd only have to paraphrase the question. In your particular case, though, the question was a very long and involved one (pretty clearly homework in retrospect). To be honest, the question should probably not be on Stackoverflow at all, as if it's homework it would be a violation of the copyright of the teacher who created the assignment. As the student added enough unique information to the question (i.e. failed homework), arguably the teacher no longer retains copyright on that particular expression of an idea.

I myself would be curious to know if Jeff Atwood asserts that he has unique copyright over our own answers. In the case of a heavily edited answer, I would suggest that he does, as it would be a case of collaboration where you would need to either avail yourself of Stackexchange's CC3 Share Alike with Attribution license or seek out your editors to gain useage permissions individually.

Clearly using the CC3 license would be a lot less trouble in this case.