# How to flag a deleted question for mod attention?

Tags: discussion

I answered a question (correctly) after which the OP just deleted it. It all happened in about 10 minutes time, so there was not a lot of time to get upvotes on the answer and prevent him from deleting it.

Read this [answered question got deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281399/i-answered-a-question-he-accepted-it-and-then-he-deleted-the-question).

**But it does not say how to flag the question. In the comments it says you should raise a flag somewhere else. Best to do so on a question of my own, or just anywhere?**

Will not post a link to the question to avoid the meta effect.

Comment: You cannot do much about this. With +10k rep you would be able to vote for undeletion.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ dude I linked it myself and explained what isn't in the Q/A

Comment: Sure, and there's not much more to say than is already there.

Comment: There's also not much point to _avoid Meta effect_ on deleted posts. What should actually happen?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it get's undeleted -> this Q is still here -> it gets downvotes.

Comment: If it's a bad question probably, if not then not. If it was a bad question why did you answer?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I used this question to flag for mod attention on the deleted question.

Comment: You probably shouldn't bother mods about that at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok, but every Q/A about this issue says to flag for mod attention. I do agree it is a minor issue. But still very annoying when you take the time to answer someone.

Comment: If your answer would have gotten upvotes, the OP won't be able to delete their question for exactly that reason. If not then not.

Comment: Next week, that poster will be posting about the injustice of getting banned for deleted posts.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know, but there is nothing stopping him from deleting it the second he gets an answer and there is a post about this, suggesting a 24h cooldown period. This has al been discussed before.

Comment: Considering how many 10K+ users hover around Meta, posting a link to it is pretty counter-productive, since we can't at least evaluate it on our own merits and see if it's even worth undeleting.  In either event, the answers in the dupe are pretty good; right now there's not much we can do about it, and flagging this wouldn't really accomplish anything since, again, undeletion of content doesn't require a moderator to intervene.

Comment: I think the same just happened to me... was wondering though - shouldn't you still see your answer in your activity log? In my case it just evaporated

Comment: @Leeor answers -> scroll to bottom -> deleted

Comment: @RMenke, thanks! Looks like he did say "thank you" before deleting it :)

Comment: Relevant:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207810/175248