# If I edit my accepted answer, will I lose reputation?

Tags: support, edits, reputation, unaccepted-answer

I have already read this [Why did I gain/lose repuation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history). Still, I have a doubt.

> If I have posted an answer which is accepted, when I edit the answer to improve it, will I lose my reputation?

**Reason for the question**

I had posted an answer and OP had added a comment on that it works. So I have updated the answer to increase the readability. During this my reputation was increased with 15+, so I assume the answer was accepted.

After I edit and save my answer, I can't find the reputation.

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/your-user-id/?tab=reputation) for reputation changes but there are no reputation changes on this day.

*Note: I'm sure I have seen a 15+ and increased reputation in the top bar.*

Comment: The OP can unaccept an answer. It probably had nothing to do with your edit, the timing was likely coincidence.

Comment: As I can't find the answer you are talking about, the reputation could have been reverted because it got deleted (with the question). Could you add a link to your answer? In case the OP deleted the question as he had an answer, perhaps a mod needs to step in to address that issue. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281399/i-answered-a-question-he-accepted-it-and-then-he-deleted-the-question) for a possible similar case and Felxo's comment.

Comment: @Matt probably [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497679/lambda-grouping-to-generic-repository-ef-with-order-by-c-sharp/37498401#37498401).

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm not sure because the OP of the linked question did not say that it works, but that it is close. Additionally, the edit did not really increase readability that much and the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37498401/timeline) does not show the accept/un-accept (could be because it was cast within a short time-span). Still, I do agree that it is the most probable question. The OP must clarify to be certain which answer he refers to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Editing an answer has no direct effect on your reputation. You may lose reputation you gained on an answer if the OP unaccepts it (which may implicitly happen if he decides to accept a different answer) or if he or other users remove their upvotes.

Editing an answer may potentially prompt other users to such behavior if the edit reduces the quality of the answer, but it has no direct effect on your reputation.

Answer (score 3):

No, editing an answer will not unaccept the answer. The OP can always accept/unaccept an answer. Note that it works differently for up- and downvotes; these *are* ['locked' in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75477/idea-behind-your-vote-is-now-locked-in-unless-this-answer-is-edited) (meaning you can't change them later than 5 minutes after voting), *unless* the post is edited.