# A new user asked an interesting question; I answered it then he left a "thank you" and detele it

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

I believe we rarely come across such user. But yesterday a new user asked an interesting question. I took effort to answer it. Then he left a "really thank you" and delete the question together with my answer. Here is the link: [Toy R code on Bayesian inference for mean of a normal distribution [data of snowfall amount]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40189329/4891738)

Well, I like that question; and I also want to keep that post on Stack Overflow for future reference. I have cast an undelete vote but is there anything else I could do?

I found there is a similar case earlier: [I answered a question, he accepted it, and then he deleted the question!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281399/4891738), so possibly this is a duplicate... But I wish I could found a way to get this thing resolved.

Comment: You could: "Lie down. Try not to cry. Cry a lot". As an option: ask the same question and answer it.