# Is it possible to know if your question is being discussed on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, meta, notifications

Is it possible to know if your question is being discussed on meta?

For example, if I do something wrong, a bad edit or whatever, and it is picked up and discussed here on meta, will I be informed in any way?

That would be a good way to have real discussions about the problem, with multiple points of view.

Comment: Not by default. But, often times, someone will add a comment to the discussed post with something like "This post is currently being discussed on meta <meta link>". That mostly is when it refers to one particular post that there is issues in the comments. If it's a more general discussion but using a certain post as an example, then probably not.

Comment: The usual "lively" voting after that happens is easy enough to notice.   That's as good as it gets if nobody posts a comment.

Comment: This should never be made automatic. What if I want to discuss a general phenomenon and use a specific post as an example, and inviting the OP to the discussion would serve no purpose at all?

Comment: It would be nice if it could be automated under certain circumstances but filtering those would be, most likely, impossible.

Comment: @Pekka 웃: Perhaps it could be limited to questions tagged [specific-question]?

Comment: @BoltClock something like that *could* be helpful but it would take some thought as to how to know which post to leave the comment on. If, for any reason, the OP added multiple links. I suppose there shouldn't be more than one SO link with that tag but it could happen. Possibly using that tag would require a link box for the OP (or editor) to enter?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187682/notify-users-when-they-are-mentioned-on-meta

Comment: see also: [Impose a 24 hour voting freeze on questions being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269191/839601)

Comment: The most I can see is if we had a button for "Discuss this on meta" like we have for "continue this discussion in chat"

Comment: @John: while I think that would be (certainly potentially) helpful, it does carry with it the same problem as JavaScript, that of worrying what "*this*" is, or is intended to be, by the person clicking the link or pressing the button...

Comment: @DavidThomas "discuss this question/answer on meta".  Just one more word.

Comment: See also [**Psst. We're talking about you over here**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313839/290085), a feature request for such notification.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is no automated system that would inform you.  If users feel that it's relevant, it's common for a comment to be posted on posts that are being discussed on meta.  Often such comments are posted either when it would be very productive for the author to join the discussion (when they didn't start it, which is actually very common) or when there's clear conflict (or even just a lengthy discussion in comments) on the post itself as to what to do, for example a post being constantly closed/reopened or where a rollback war is going on.

Comment: *There is no automated system that would inform you.* Well most times it doesn't take long and all of the sudden you get downvotes, then you know it :)

Comment: @Rizier123: Could be reddit, chat, you name it...