# How to tell if a question/answer has been referenced on SO meta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta

When viewing a question or answer, is there any indication that is has been mentioned in a SO Meta discussion? If not, would it be possible to add something like this?

It seems like one advantage would be to educate users about potential problems that haven't resulted in closing the question. It could also help a user understand that if a question receives unusually high traffic or ["meta effect"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/impose-a-24-hour-voting-freeze-on-questions-being-discussed-on-meta) votes, these are not necessarily indicative of the importance or helpfulness of a question.

On the other hand, I suppose there might be disadvantages, too (e.g., possibly making "meta effects" worse).

Comment: [Related non-feature-request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297264/is-it-possible-to-know-if-your-question-is-being-discussed-on-meta-stack-overflo)

Comment: Generally, when a specific question is being discussed, someone will add a comment to that effect, but there's currently no "official" indication.

Comment: one can search by post URL, as in this example: [url:"meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22meta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F255583%22)