# Should I upvote an answer for a topic I'm not proficient in?

Tags: discussion, voting

If an answer is well-focused for the scope of the question, shows research effort, cites credible sources, is presented clearly, and otherwise looks like a very good answer, should I upvote it even if I don't know enough about the question's subject matter to evaluate the answer's technical correctness?

The upvote tooltip for answers simply says "This answer is useful". The strictest interpretation of that would be to say that I should not upvote an answer unless it was useful to me personally. Is this an accurate criterion for upvoting an answer?

Comment: Logical answer: You can vote however you would like. Someone-elses-answer: Well, what if the answer didn't end up answer the question, or was wrong... vote for things you can vouch for.

Comment: In practice, and culturally, the answer is yes. This does emit corner cases where malicious, or just insidiously confident but misguided, answers that are dressed nicely can amass upvotes before someone finally, if ever, points out the glaring problem.

Comment: There is a large grey area here. It is common for the OP to upvote questions. However, in quite a few (though far from all) cases the person asking the question is almost by definition unqualified to judge which answer is "good" or even "correct", since this person obviously doesn't have enough understanding of the topic at hand...

Comment: In almost all cases the OP at least knows that the difficulty they were facing has been overcome by the answer, @Carpetsmoker. That's not nothing.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It would depend on the question; in "I want output foo, but get output bar"-type of questions that's true. In others, not so much. Example: I marked [an answer as accepted here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35935965/660921), but how do I know that's actually true? I *think* it is, but obviously I'm not *really* qualified to make that decision... And even if it works, it doesn't have to be a "good" answer (see: the `chmod 777` thread, but many other examples can be found).

Comment: Presumably that answer makes some assertions that have implications which can be further tested in the same way that led to the original question, @Carpetsmoker.

Comment: Votes are the grease that keep the SO wheel turning.  Did you learn something from that post, anything at all?  Then it was useful to you so voting for it is appropriate.  In general it is pretty uncommon to learn nothing from a well documented answer, but if it is quantum physics or you have any reason to assume that the post might not be accurate then don't.

Comment: Feel free to cast your positive/negative vote; rep is free on SO and ppl like free stuff.

Comment: @Omar Downvotes on answers are not free,am afraid...

Comment: @machine -1 isn't a big deal, that's why voting system is misused.

Comment: Yes, because it also highlights which areas that programmers have the most problems with. Take this JS Closure problem for instance. It has over 5K upvotes. If everyone understood Closures intuitively, then this link & page wouldn't have a reason to exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work When something gets that high of visibility, it's probably a good candidate for a community wiki page.

Comment: "This answer is useful" doesn't necessarily mean you found it personally useful for a problem that you were having. It could be useful in that it helped give a clear explanation. I find a wrench a useful tool for loosening bolts even when I don't personally have any bolts that need loosening.

Comment: From some of the (dreadful) questions I see getting an upvote almost as soon as they're posted it's clear some people just upvote no matter what.

Comment: an accurate criteria -> an accurate criterion

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Please do not vote -- in either direction -- without being a confident judge of the contents of the answer. This doesn't mean you have to be an *expert*, but you do have to be able to understand **what the answer is saying**, **how it applies to the problem** (though not necessarily the problem in the question -- you might have a slightly different problem), and **whether it's a good or bad contribution** to solving the problem<sup>*</sup>.

If you don't understand the answer, but vote on it anyways, then I think you're misleading future readers. We use post score to say something like "This is good. This is information that you want or need. It will help you get where you're trying to go", and post score is just the aggregate of all the votes. If you vote without being able to make that statement, you're diluting the signal derived from the judgements of everyone else who voted.

---

<sup>*</sup>I use "problem" fairly loosely here: you might not have busted code or even any particular task you're trying to perform. You might have a more general, speculative question like [the one Carpetsmoker linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35935965/). There's still an answer you can explicitly evaluate before voting.

Comment: a side-effect of this policy is that answers in niche fields will not receive very many votes, causing a decreased incentive to answer niche questions. the obvious response to that might be "well, we answer posts to help people, not to gain imaginary reputation points", but the gamification of stack overflow means that people inescapably *do* want to gain imaginary reputation points (and that's what makes this site work).

Comment: to be clear: i'm not disputing the validity of your answer here, i merely want to explain why i thought it might be advantageous to encourage voting in areas where users do not have technical proficiency.

Comment: Even in an area you're not totally proficient in, I think you can still make an informed judgement, rather than just a "sounds good, looks good, thumbs up!" I've upvoted a few Haskell answers, even though I haven't made it past chapter 3 of the book I'm using; I checked them out to the best of my ability and made a decision. I could have been wrong, but I'm confident enough to tell a peer "yes, there's something useful there". My point is that you should vote on the contents of the answer, not the appearance. (Although appearance certainly helps in getting to the content.)

Comment: The downside of this policy is that simple answers which can easily be validated (even by noobs) will gain more votes/reputation than expert answers whose accuracy can only be confirmed by other experts. To cover that, we would need to make votes by experts (via tag reputation) count more?

Comment: @Bergi - I don't think this is anywhere close to be main reason why simple questions get more votes - way more people need answer to basic questions than to more interesting, but narrower once.

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of what happens when a post is discussed on meta. Trolls cast votes irresponsibly and mods _claim_ they can't stop such behavior.

Comment: @Omar yeah it would be about time to let all links from Meta to SO become "No Participation" links (like Reddit, like `np.stackoverflow.com`), where you get a warning that you shouldn't vote.

Comment: So you think one should vote on an answer based on the person who answered, @Bergi?

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't think this would make any difference, trolls will still vote neglecting any warning. Voting should be disabled on any post being discussed on meta.

Comment: This [has been suggested formally](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/impose-a-24-hour-voting-freeze-on-questions-being-discussed-on-meta), @Omar.

Comment: @JoshCaswell 19 months and counting...

Comment: @JoshCaswell: no, that's not what I meant. Every user can write an expert answer that can only be assessed by expert voters.

Comment: @Omar don't hold your breath. There are [same concerns about hot questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269191/impose-a-24-hour-voting-freeze-on-questions-being-discussed-on-meta#comment82884_269252) which are much easier to fix / tame but which hang around for even longer. SE management simply wants moar answers and moar views and moar votes too much to be able to reason rationally about anything that seems to be going against it...

Comment: ...Guess they've yet to learn that lemmings rampage is not a substitute for knowledge crowdsoursing. Currently they run straight to the point when search engines will have to downgrade their relevance to that of Reddit (notice how reddit's "wildly popular" threads don't pollute search results)

Answer (score 37):

If, despite all of its other qualities, you cannot, in good conscience, say that "This answer is useful" because you cannot make an informed opinion on its technical veracity, then you are free to abstain from voting if doing so makes you uncomfortable.

Comment: I cannot determine the technical veracity of this answer, so I'm abstaining from voting.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Remember, [voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) ;)

Comment: Oh yeah, well then -1 for no freehand circles.

Comment: I like the number of commas you managed to jam into this one, but I was let down by the waffly ending, so +0.5. Wait...waffles and jam! +a million!

Comment: "free to abstain from voting if doing so makes you uncomfortable" --> "should abstain from voting". Score is usually (or at least should be)  an indication of answer correctness to future visitors.

Comment: Voting is different on meta... except meta.SE. :/

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I think, possibly, a couple more commas could be added, if desired, that is, after the word "voting", and, less plausibly, after the word "opinion," but, to be honest, the word that should, almost certainly, be followed by a comma, is "useful."

Comment: @Wildcard I would advocate that, to the extent of my knowledge and experience, the last comma, in your sentence, is incorrect, in the sense that it should not be there at all. ;)

Comment: "free to abstain from voting if doing so makes you uncomfortable" is not clear whether "doing so" refers to "abstain from voting" or "voting". I mean, I know what you mean, but I stumbled on the sentence at first.

Answer (score 5):

In practice, and culturally, the answer is yes. I think this is clear for the simple reason that you upvote answers you learn from. And you generally learn things in areas you are not already an expert in.

We can only take so much responsibility for how credulous readers are regarding what they find here. Generally if I see a well-written or well-upvoted answer I trust it. But I take my day job seriously and don't make security-critical or production-critical decisions based solely on what I learn here.

Corner cases do arise where an insidious answer that's dressed well amasses upvotes before another expert catches the glitch. The answer will then live with something like +11/-3 votes and one comment by the expert explaining that the whole thing is nonsense. This does happen.

Comment: I disagree. If a user can't evaluate a question and its answer, he can't tell for sure whether he is truly learning something useful or not. Also by blindly up-voting good looking answers he would deceive future visitors in some occasions. Up-voting should be used for **useful** and **correct** answers; not for good looking answers.

Answer (score 3):

You should not vote on answer in such case.

Reasons like "good writing style" or "a lot of hand circles" are wrong reason to upvote an *answer*. Note that these "shows research effort, cites credible sources, is presented clearly" are good reasons to upvote *question* as anyone should be able to at least understand question.

It also does not sound like the answer was useful to you nor you know if it actually answers the question at all / provides good (or at least commonly accepted) solution.

Voting disclaimer: votes are yours to spend in whatever way you want. Formally one does not need *any reason* to vote one way or another.

Answer (score 3):

This is the logic that I typically apply when encountering questions in the wild on StackOverflow, and most of the Stack Exchange. I consider "understand" and "understood" as literal. When evaluating `ApproveOfAnswer`, approval is my vote of confidence that not only do I consider it a good answer, but I wouldn't be hesitant to use that solution myself.

[image: voting on stack exchange graphic]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the contents of the `ApproveOfAnswer()` procedure?

Comment: No problem; updated. It was getting cramped for a browser's read-friendly graphic inside the dimension limits.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is to vote if you found the answer useful and helpful.

How much effort went into an answer and how well it was researched is not usually criteria I use when deciding to upvote. An answer could have been well-researched and still be wrong, and it could be very quickly given and still be helpful. And I think being helpful is what matters.

Also, if you don't have a good understanding of a topic, it may be hard to judge how well researched it was.

Answer (score 1):

What is learning? It's when you go from not knowing to knowing. Upvote if you, personally, *learn* from the answer. You said:

> The strictest interpretation ... would be to say that I should not upvote an answer unless it was useful to me personally

Exactly so. Obviously I don't have to be *competent* in a field to be helped by an answer in that field; this, indeed, is *why* the answer helped me. But the answer has to be of practical help to me, in actual fact. In a nutshell, my upvote means: "Thanks, I needed that."