# Upvoting members without enough upvotes or activity to encourage them

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I give a series of 3 upvotes for:

1. Members who have been here for a long time, who log in but either do not seem to contribute anymore or contribute very rarely (I hope to encourage them)
2. Members who wrote a lot of recent answers with few or no upvotes (so that they will not fall into the first group)

I know the general principle is to upvote a post which is interesting, and avoid upvoting targeted at members, but as I upvote for mere encouragement of the members who belong to the groups mentioned above, I wonder if what I am doing is a reasonable, or behavior to avoid?

Comment: Just make sure any content you're upvoting is worth it. Then it's fine. If it's not worth an upvote then it's not fine.

Comment: Related: [What exactly is “artificial inflation of reputation”, and where is the line?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318497/1026459)

Comment: I  think you may have misunderstood what we are saying below - the stuff about voting rings and such is a joke. Nobody is seriously being accused of anything.

Answer (score 20):

[Robert is correct to point out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326458/603977) that serial voting can get you in trouble with the authorities, but I think it's important to consider *why* that kind of voting is a problem.

Voting affects a post's score. The post's score indicates its usefulness: for an answer, how correct and complete it is as a solution; for a question, how clear and findable it is as an expression of a problem.

If you vote on a post without having read, understood, and judged the actual content, **you're lying** to everyone who views that post later. You're distorting the score, making the post seem to have been reviewed by a peer who thinks it's good (or bad).

Think about that the next time you're searching for an answer.

**Votes are not about people**: users get rewarded because their posts are judged to be useful. If you start doing it the other way around, you're making this place less helpful.

See also [Should I upvote an answer for a topic I'm not proficient in?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318984/should-i-upvote-an-answer-for-a-topic-im-not-proficient-in/318994#318994)

Comment: I'd also suggest that "rewarding" a user just for being new and making an effort may give then a false impression of the quality expectation and may come back to hurt them later.

Comment: I love that "**you're lying**" sentence: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python/14836239#14836239) "answer" says  only "Yes".  It got dozens of upvotes. I wonder how you can call the answerer and those who upvoted that "post" which does not even enough informative to be a comment. (P.S. Nothing personal, there are thousands of such "very good quality answers with hundreds, or even thousands, of upvotes)

Answer (score 17):

You need to vote on [posts, not people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/188189). Targeting people is serial voting and may get you banned.

Comment: True. But it's unlikely to ever be a problem if the OP sticks with casting 3 votes max. I've done the same in the past - seen a new member who really knows their stuff, but is getting *zero* feedback, went through their profile and looked for the most upvote-worthy content to vote on. No more than 2-3 (if just because otherwise the serial voting process kicks in.) It's not the end of the world.

Comment: Trying to avoid the serial voting mechanism because you think you know how it works may backfire. If the person really knows their stuff they'll get upvotes eventually, just have a little patience that the system works instead of trying to subvert it.

Comment: My working theory is that @Pekka웃 is a very sophisticated sock puppet operated by several thousand new-ish users.

Comment: @meagar WE ARE NOT!!!!!!!!! I mean, *I* am not.

Comment: The voting patterns are all there, if only I could [put the pieces together](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/600x315/40/f8/6f/40f86fca6c2be00fda05e5de41d15a8f.jpg), I could bring down the largest voting ring in SO history!

Comment: @meagar I wouldn't go there if I were you. We've brought down moderators before.

Comment: We are legio.... I mean pekka!...