# Correct answer, but far too advanced

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Here is [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47504579/1270789), a user struggling with the basics of `std::cin` and sort algorithms. A C++ God comes in with a [high-level ninja answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47505123/1270789), but should I down-vote as "This answer is not useful" to the OP as I suspect this would go right over their head, and doesn't teach why they were having their problem of duplicating the last line of the file.

(My personal decision is to neither up- nor down-vote in this case)

Comment: OP could not be bothered to create MCVE for they problem... Maybe you should edit question with good MCVE and clear explanation of the problem (or just vote to close)

Comment: What's your question anyway? If a user should up or downvote?

Comment: Two very basic principles apply.  1: SO is not a forum, we write answers for the next thousand programmers that find the question back. 2: Use your votes which ever way you deem appropriate.  So asking for help on deciding how to vote is not useful, it is entirely up to you.  Deciding not the vote is a conscientious decision and just fine, surely appropriate here given your stance.

Comment: That answer is recommending the use of `std::sort`, from the standard C++ library, which is what professional C++ programmers would often use for sorting purposes. Generally speaking, it has value. Downvoting for its extensive use of mechanisms provided by the standard library, albeit a valid decision, is in my opinion a poor one.

Comment: Even though you are free to vote as you like, please don't vote with assumption that you're some other users. Answers are for anyone and future readers, not just OP.

Comment: *SO is not a forum, we write answers for the next thousand programmers that find the question back.* I agree with that, but i think the point is that only programmers that are stuck at this problem (so beginners) will come across the question and this advanced answer. So mostly beginners will find the question/answer so i think the answer should always be like in the same *skill level* with the problem asked about. There is no sense in a super advanced answer about a beginners topic, since beginners dont understand those answers and advanced programmers dont deal with those issues anymore.

Comment: @L.Guthardt 'since beginners dont understand those answers' - maybe, but they do have an answer and they can investigate it to find out how it works.  It's how many people learn stuff.  'the answer should always be like in the same skill level with the problem' - you suggest aadding yet more condtaints on answers that require yet more effort from the skilled and experienced developers who answer questions?  No!

Comment: @MartinJames I agree with you, but I still think that the question and answer should be rough around the same league. At least that the OP isnt completely lost.

Comment: Upvoted because this is a reasonable Meta question even though I [vehemently disagree with the premise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359884/603977).

Comment: @MartinJames That you consider, "posting an answer that's actually helpful and understandable to people with the problem being asked about in the question" to be an unreasonable restriction on people posting answers is rather telling.  I don't consider that an unreasonable restriction at all.  Those experts that are taking their time to answers questions are hopefully doing so in order to help people with that problem actually find a solution.  If the people searching for a solution to that problem can't find one, then they're not doing that, and the votes should reflect that.

Answer (score 7):

If an asker doesn't understand an answer to their question, they have several avenues of recourse:

- Ignore the answer and wait for another
- Comment on the answer asking for further explanation
- Accept the answer, do their best to integrate the solution, and post a new question for clarification, as necessary

With some crossover possible between these options (and perhaps some others that I've missed).

The asker is not a helpless lamb whom you need to defend from the horrors of having to think. And, probably more importantly, **the OP is not the only person for whom the answer is written**.

Now, your vote is yours to use freely to express your judgement. If you, [having read and considered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318994/603977) the answer, believe that it so many wasted bytes that will not help anyone, and that the world would be better had it not been posted, then by all means give it your mark of disapproval.

But please don't cast your vote as some kind of censorious proxy because you're offended by expertise on someone else's behalf.

Comment: "[...] the horrors of having to think." SJWs these days: "They spoke about [topic] in class today, I was forced to think about it, they should be expelled!"

Comment: Notice that all of the options you have listed are, entirely coincidentally, exactly the same things you'd do if the answer is simply wrong, or doesn't work at all.

Comment: Uh, sometimes, sure...but the fact that I would dump water on my living room rug if it were on fire [does not allow you to conclude _from a wet rug_ that there was a fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent). Those are also the _OP's options_, not a bystander's.