# Should we provide professional-level advice to newbies?

Tags: discussion, new-users

*Note: This question possibly applies to C++ tag only. I'm not frequently viewing other tags, so I'm not sure whether this situation occurs anywhere else.*

Imagine a question like following (an example of typical, very newbie question that will get downvoted to oblivion):

> **My array doesn't work!**
> My array always prints some strange value at the end, I don't know why, please help:
>
> ```
> #include <bits/stdc++.h>
> using namespace std; int main() {
>     int n;
>     cout << "How many elements?";
>     cin >> n;
>     int myArray[n];
>     for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
>         cin >> myArray[i];
>     for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
>         cout << myArray[i];
> ```

The answer is pretty simple - in C++ array indexing starts at 0 and should end at `n - 1`.
However, the first three comments would commonly look like this (slightly exaggerated - you'd not always see all of them, but they are common nevertheless):

> See [Why should I not #include bits/stdc++.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?rq=1)
>
> This is not valid C++, Variable Length Arrays are not allowed in the standard
>
> Use `std::vector` instead.

All of these comments are valid concers *for production-level code*. At the same time, they are not related *at all* to the problem in question. They will just confuse asker. Fixing these problems won't help *now*.

Of course, all of these things will bite back eventually (just wait till OP writes `sort()` function and it won't compile). But that's not the point.

---

I remember when I first started to learn programming. I learned lots of stuff by heart:

> I need to add `include <cstdlib>` and `include <time.h>`, so I can get random number using this: `srand(time(NULL)); int r = rand() * 6;`

I had no idea what `include` actually does and why do I need all these for simple random number. But **that's what my teacher told me to do**. If he told me to add `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, I'd do that and wouldn't bother what that means.

Moreover, when I were on arrays and loops level, I had no idea what classes and objects are, not to mention how could I possibly use `std::vector`, a templated class, instead.

---

I believe anyone will eventually learn all those practices when they advance their programming skills and start to learn what is good and what is bad. Or they'll hit the problems, due to which they are considered "bad practices". Or even by getting employed / sending pull request to open-source and getting tons of negative comments on their code.

So, **should we provide "good, but unrelated advice" to people obviously new to programming**?
Does it change anything for the newbies? And what about "welcomeness" of such comments?

Comment: Answers are better if they address not just the question asker, but every future visitor with the same problem. So yes, answers that also address other issues in the question *are more useful to future visitors*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This kind of questions is very rarely capable of being useful to anyone. It will get downvoted and closed for lack of research. But the problem is that these comments help *noone*, neither OP nor future visitors (if any). Future visitor will either know about those bad practices, or (more likely) will be completely uninterested in them, because they are not connected to the problem.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen If you think that the question isn't, and can never be, useful to anyone, then address *that* problem, not some comments on it.  Spending time trying to get rid of comments on a post that you think should be deleted entirely is just wasting time.

Comment: Somewhat related, although about answers, not comments: [Correct answer but far too advanced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359868/correct-answer-but-far-too-advanced/)

Comment: SO is a bad place for naive questions. It wasn't designed for that, and no amount of *welcomeness* can fix it. *Stack Overflow was definitely designed as a fairly strict system of peer review, which is great (IMNSHO, obviously) for already practicing professionals, but **pretty much everything you would not want as a student or beginner.** This is why I cringe so hard I practically turn myself inside out when people on Twitter mention that they have pointed their students at Stack Overflow.* [Jeff Atwood](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/)

Comment: Somebody taught you a very bad practice, surely not an SO user.  Now you'll have to do the hard work to unlearn it again.  Google "c++ why is rand bad" to get ahead.

Comment: No, because that is not what comments are for. That doesn't stop people from using comments to provide advice (guilty as charged), but the answer to "should you" is still **no**.

Comment: if you tag a question [tag:c++] you are stepping in the lion's cage. Tag it [tag:c++] and [tag:c] you're stepping in the cage wearing a bacon tuxedo.

Answer (score 10):

> They will just confuse asker.

I don't care about the asker.

If *any user* reads that question and walks away with the idea that any of the following is true:

1. Variable-length arrays are legal C++ syntax.
2. `<bits/stdc++.h>` is a real, standard C++ header.
3. `using namespace std` is a good idea.

Then we are doing a *disservice* to that user. It's bad enough that there are so many ignorant tutorials spreading bad information to users. We don't need to be part of that. So if these comments improve the chances of users realizing that this is not good code, then so much the better.

This is not about "professional assistance". It's about "not misinforming people" and not regularizing dangerous language usage patterns.

> I believe anyone will eventually learn all those practices when they advance their programming skills and start to learn what is good and what is bad.

Reality stands in stark opposition to your beliefs.

Answer (score 2):

Remember:  we're here to *help*, not hold their hand.

I don't see either of those comments as particularly *helpful*, but I also don't want us to go out of our way to hold someone's hand when they may not be familiar with code.

Conversely, presenting someone with a whole bunch of production-grade pomp and circumstance is *also* not helpful.  Answerers need to strike a balance between "good" code and "helpful" code.

Simple takewaway:  if the commentators don't think the question is *capable* of being answered until it's fixed, then they should vote to close accordingly.  If they *do*, then their comments should be fixated on gaining clarification into the code the OP is trying to write.  If they're neutral, then perhaps they could just *not* commentate?